# How do I run a node.js app as a background service?

Tags: node.js, process, background, server, daemon

Since this post has gotten a lot of attention over the years, I've listed the top solutions per platform at the bottom of this post.

---

**Original post**:

I want my node.js server to run in the background, i.e.: when I close my terminal I want my server to keep running. I've googled this and came up with this [tutorial](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/run_nodejs_as_a_service_on_ubuntu_karmic/), however it doesn't work as intended. So instead of using that daemon script, I thought I just used the output redirection (the `2>&1 >> file` part), but this too does not exit - I get a blank line in my terminal, like it's waiting for output/errors.

I've also tried to put the process in the background, but as soon as I close my terminal the process is killed as well.

So how can I leave it running when I shut down my local computer?

---

**Top solutions**:

- [Systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042953/339122) (Linux)
- [Launchd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25998406/339122) (Mac)
- [node-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15616912/339122) (Windows)
- [PM2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005935/339122) (Node.js)

Comment: I think he meant to shut down his local system

Comment: he meant closing a ssh session terminates the task

Comment: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2 is a highly maintained and very stable process manager, give it a try !

Comment: you can use screen (http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference)

Comment: You can use nohup, search in google how to use this.

Answer (score 611, accepted):

Copying my own answer from [How do I run a Node.js application as its own process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681067/how-to-run-a-node-js-application-as-its-own-process/28542093#28542093)

**2015 answer**: nearly every Linux distro comes with systemd, which means **forever, monit, PM2, etc are  no longer necessary - your OS already handles these tasks**.

Make a `myapp.service` file (replacing 'myapp' with your app's name, obviously):

```
[Unit]
Description=My app

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/myapp/app.js
Restart=always
User=nobody
# Note Debian/Ubuntu uses 'nogroup', RHEL/Fedora uses 'nobody'
Group=nogroup
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myapp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Note if you're new to Unix:** `/var/www/myapp/app.js` should have `#!/usr/bin/env node` on the very first line and have the executable mode turned on `chmod +x app.js`.

Copy your service file into the `/etc/systemd/system`.

Start it with `systemctl start myapp`.

Enable it to run on boot with `systemctl enable myapp`.

See logs with `journalctl -u myapp`

This is taken from **[How we deploy node apps on Linux, 2018 edition](https://web.archive.org/web/20180212163211/https://certsimple.com/blog/deploy-node-on-linux)**, which also includes commands to generate an AWS/DigitalOcean/Azure CloudConfig to build Linux/node servers (including the `.service` file).

Comment: Upstart , when available is also a good solution. either way, you should not rely on a nodejs process to keep your nodejs daemon running. This is one task for the OS solely. 
killall nodejs and forever is gone....

Comment: Note that it's also possible to run systemd services as a user. See for example [this tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User). You can put your service file in `~/.config/systemd/user`, start it with `systemctl --user start myapp`, enable it with `systemctl --user enable myapp`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is what i want pure and clear

Comment: I've accepted this answer instead of the "forever" answer, since I also think this is the best way to do it. There are similar answers for Mac & Windows, but I'm guessing the majority is looking for a Linux solution.

Comment: in EC2 AMI path /etc/systemd/system does not exist. Can you point what is the correct path in AWS EC2 Linux AMI?

Comment: Just noting that this method didn't work with Ubuntu 3.13. Ubuntu uses Upstart, not systemd/systemctrl

Comment: @danyim Yep, Ubuntu's the last major distro not to. 16.04 (the next LTS) uses systemd.

Comment: Any idea of how to make something similar on a web server ?

Comment: i cant find also the systemd folder in centOS 6.8

Comment: I got a Failed at step GROUP spawning ... No such process error. Failed to start myapp. The file and directory are definitely correct. Any ideas why my service might not want to start?

Comment: @xxstevenxo That sounds like a question rather than a comment!

Comment: @mikemaccana you're absolutely correct. I ended up figuring it out anyways. In order to run the app as a node service, I had to include the path to node before the path to my app. All is working wonderfully now.

Comment: @xxstevenxo Sounds like node isn't in $PATH. Use the nodesource packages linked to from nodejs.org, they'll install it properly (and help you update easier)

Comment: Can't stop the service. 
systemctl stop myapp 
not working. How to reload the service by modifying the code?

Comment: @murad Maybe post that as a question somewhere?

Comment: @mikemaccana What about `monit`? https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-monitor-and-restart-linux-unix-service.html

Comment: @mikemaccana The fact that the JS community felt it was necessary to create ForeverJS is an indication of their ignorance that the Linux/Unix community would have already encountered this problem, recognized it as a general need, and written a solid tool to solve it.  A tool like `monit`

Comment: be careful with this; by making it a service, you restrict it's ability to talk to the desktop. This can be annoying when you're writing something like a server that you use to simulate keyboard events in a drawing program.

Comment: I set ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /mypath/index.js and designated User and Group (instead of nobody) to make it work. Otherwise it will complain something like 'Failed at step GROUP spawning /usr/bin/node: No such process'

Comment: @HowardLiu Yes, if you don't have a group called `nobody` you might want to try `nogroup` - different Linux distros use different conventions.

Comment: @HowardLiu Also you're missing an interpreter - node should be at the top of 'index.js'

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I was wasting my time searching for "forever" and "pm2". This is just native and simple.

Comment: This worked beautifully! Had to find my node executable though (whereis node) and add that to the shebang.

Comment: @mrg You can also add the path to the `Environment` section above. `node` normally installs to `/usr/bin` using the Linux distro packages from https://nodejs.org but you might have it in a different spot if it's installed somewhere else.

Comment: @ApexND you should probably check the user and group exist then, and make them.

Comment: I've created the most bare minimum package to create a service file: https://www.npmjs.com/package/linux_service_maker
Forks welcome at:
https://github.com/joshivaibhavs/linuxServiceMaker.js

Comment: Don't forget to `chmod +x app.js`.

Comment: Good point @InxaneNinja I've added it to the instructions!

Comment: After a while of fiddling with this I've noticed sometimes the Node versions aren't right. I advise to set ExecStarts as "node app.js" instead of running it directly using the shebang line.

Comment: Couldn't get services to work on EC2 recently. Decided to give PM2 a shot. PM2 is an amazing project, incredibly user friendly (specifically for node users), has a wonderful CLI with visuals. With monitoring, restoring on reboot, simple log management, etc. Saved me maybe hours of work and maintenance. This will be my go-to solution going forward.

Answer (score 256):

**UPDATE** - As mentioned in one of the answers below, [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) has some really nice functionality missing from forever.  Consider using it.

**Original Answer**

Use [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup):

```
nohup node server.js &
```

**EDIT** I wanted to add that the accepted answer is really the way to go.  I'm using forever on instances that need to stay up.  I like to do `npm install -g forever` so it's in the node path and then just do `forever start server.js`

Comment: cool part to know: `nohup` stands for `no hangup` which comes from the old days, where you wanted you keep a process alive when you "hangup" your modem.

Comment: nowadays it's rather the name of signal 1 that processes receive to warn that the user closed the shell (or lost modem connection, of course :P)

Comment: It's not the best solution because if the app encounters an uncaught error the node process will exit and not restart. Still, it's a reasonable option for development.

Comment: How would I add environmental variables to that? eg: PORT=80 node server.js

Comment: Check out this answer from SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825460/nohup-verbose-1-perl-script-pl

Comment: I'll go so far as to say this and the selected answer is the best of both worlds.  Use forever in its "in code" version and then use nohup to start.

Comment: pm2 is buggy. You should fully test PM2 before go production

Comment: @user3304007 the forever.js solutions will restart the app if it crashes.

Comment: I've used pm2 for 2 years. It would stop responding sometimes while running node app in cluster mode. So, I switched back to use `myapp.service` solution mentioned above now.

Comment: nohup logs everything to an output file, nohup.out which may cause a full disk.

Comment: This is also a literal joke among sysadmins about how people who don't know how to administer systems run services.

Answer (score 249):

You can use Forever, A simple CLI tool for ensuring that a given node script runs continuously (i.e. forever):
https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever

Comment: With latest node I was unable to get it to stop an app via the script name (error) - also - generally misbehaving (was on OS-X) - all built from source, oddly. Left things in a bad state, didn't fill me with confidence.

Comment: While nohup does the trick, forever is a better solution as it daemonizes the process. Great tool!

Comment: Just by the way, a simpler tutorial is available here: [Keep a node.js server up with Forever](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever)

Comment: I did use Forever for a while, at the beginning everything seems ok but then disaster happened. Forever could not manage the processes anymore and let them run wild. Still struggling to find a better solution. I will try to use nohup

Comment: Will Forever automatically restart if the server restarts (for example after a power outage)?

Comment: Geoffrey- no, you'll need to do `forever start /path/to/yourApp.js` in your server startup script.

Comment: Forever doesn't seem to work on node 0.8 +. Use something like [jesus](https://npmjs.org/package/jesus) instead.

Comment: Forever works fine for me, using node 0.8 and even node 0.10. Maybe you need to update your local version of forever, @Druska

Comment: Does `forever` automatically start your script whenever you reboot?

Comment: No matter what I do when I exit the SSH session I cannot access my application. Tried - "nohup server.js &" , "forever start server.js", "nohup supervisor server.js &" everything. But when I exit ssh connection it stops. Any idea?

Comment: Ironically? only used **forever** for a while. Kept having issues with it. Now use **pm2** instead. Much clearer and so far no issues.

Comment: **This answer is badly out of date** Every current Linux distro uses .service files, which do not need forever or pm2 or any other external software.

Answer (score 78):

This might not be the accepted way, but I do it with screen, especially while in development because I can bring it back up and fool with it if necessary.

```
screen
node myserver.js
>>CTRL-A then hit D
```

The screen will detach and survive you logging off. Then you can get it back back doing screen -r. Hit up the screen manual for more details. You can name the screens and whatnot if you like.

Comment: Also, tmux is nice.  Works like screen (CTRL-B is default instead of CTRL-A, but is configurable).  Tmux has panels (split screens).

Comment: i'm using this since a couple of weeks for a meteor app. `$screen -dr' for detaching and reattaching might be required occasionally.

Comment: For me the easiest way to have the job done. But I agree, not the best solution

Comment: This solution does not persist after a reboot of system

Comment: In as much as it is not the best solution, for development purposes, it is the best, as, it doesn't require additional dependencies/installations. So +1. (Forgotten about screens entirely)
:)

Comment: This is a literal joke among sysadmins about how people who don't know how to administer systems run services.

Answer (score 73):

**2016 Update:**
The node-windows/mac/linux series uses a common API across all operating systems, so it is absolutely a relevant solution. However; node-linux generates systemv init files. As systemd continues to grow in popularity, it is realistically a better option on Linux. PR's welcome if anyone wants to add systemd support to node-linux :-)

*Original Thread:*

This is a pretty old thread now, but [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) provides another way to create background services on Windows. It is loosely based on the `nssm` concept of using an `exe` wrapper around your node script. However; it uses `winsw.exe` instead and provides a configurable node wrapper for more granular control over how the process starts/stops on failures. These processes are available like any other service:

[image]

The module also bakes in some event logging:

[image]

Daemonizing your script is accomplished through code. For example:

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
  name:'Hello World',
  description: 'The nodejs.org example web server.',
  script: 'C:\\path\\to\\my\\node\\script.js'
});

// Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
// process is available as a service.
svc.on('install',function(){
  svc.start();
});

// Listen for the "start" event and let us know when the
// process has actually started working.
svc.on('start',function(){
  console.log(svc.name+' started!\nVisit http://127.0.0.1:3000 to see it in action.');
});

// Install the script as a service.
svc.install();
```

The module supports things like capping restarts (so bad scripts don't hose your server) and growing time intervals between restarts.

Since node-windows services run like any other, it is possible to manage/monitor the service with whatever software you already use.

Finally, there are no `make` dependencies. In other words, a straightforward `npm install -g node-windows` will work. You don't need Visual Studio, .NET, or node-gyp magic to install this. Also, it's MIT and BSD licensed.

In full disclosure, I'm the author of this module. It was designed to relieve the exact pain the OP experienced, but with tighter integration into the functionality the Operating System already provides. I hope future viewers with this same question find it useful.

Comment: I've now ported this to [node-mac](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-mac), providing the same functionality on OSX.

Comment: I have come to the point to schedule a couple of Node programs and stand before a decision to choose node-windows, Forever or Kue. I lean towards node-windows but would like to understand why not not to use Forever or Kue when I want to schedule and monitor a dozen of node programs. Some running forever. Need monitoring too.

Comment: Node-windows uses the native OS for managing background services, and the native event log for logging. Forever has it's own custom monitoring & logging. I wrote an article on this at https://medium.com/p/2a602ea657a2


It sounds like you need to schedule your scripts, not run them all the time as background services. Projects like Kue and Agenda are designed for this. Node-windows & Forever serve a different purpose.

Comment: @Corey, how do i run the example included in node-mac ?, from terminal, i tried node install.js, but it does not seem to pickup helloworld.js

Comment: @Edwin - Might be best to open a new question with more detail about the problem, including the code you are using.

Comment: sorted, node install.js actually worked, but i needed to view mac log to see the ouputs of heeloworld.js.
Great module btw;

Answer (score 59):

If you simply want to run the script uninterrupted until it completes you can use `nohup` as already mentioned in the answers here. However, none of the answers provide a full command that also logs `stdin` and `stdout`.

```
nohup node index.js >> app.log 2>&1 &
```

- The `>>` means append to `app.log`.
- `2>&1` makes sure that errors are also send to `stdout` and added to the `app.log`.
- The ending `&` makes sure your current terminal is disconnected from command so you can continue working.

If you want to run a node server (or something that should start back up when the server restarts) you should use [systemd / systemctl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042953/99923).

Answer (score 32):

**UPDATE**: i updated to include the latest from pm2:

for many use cases, using a systemd service is the simplest and most appropriate way to manage a node process. for those that are running numerous node processes or independently-running node microservices in a single environment, pm2 is a more full featured tool.

https://github.com/unitech/pm2

http://pm2.io

- it has a really useful monitoring feature -> pretty 'gui' for command line monitoring of multiple processes with `pm2 monit` or process list with `pm2 list`
- organized Log management -> `pm2 logs`
- other stuff:

  > - Behavior configuration
  > - Source map support
  > - PaaS Compatible
  > - Watch & Reload
  > - Module System
  > - Max memory reload
  > - Cluster Mode
  > - Hot reload
  > - Development workflow
  > - Startup Scripts
  > - Auto completion
  > - Deployment workflow
  > - Keymetrics monitoring
  > - API

Answer (score 29):

Try to run this command if you are using nohup -

```
nohup npm start 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null&
```

You can also use forever to start server

```
forever start -c "npm start" ./
```

PM2 also supports `npm start`

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

Comment: thnx, this worked perfectly. 
`pm2 start npm -- start`

Comment: Thanks, I'm using NestJS so I tried to run:  [forever start -c "npm run start" ./]
and it worked really well!

Answer (score 22):

If you are running OSX, then the easiest way to produce a true system process is to use `launchd` to launch it.

Build a plist like this, and put it into the /Library/LaunchDaemons with the name `top-level-domain.your-domain.application.plist` (you need to be root when placing it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>top-level-domain.your-domain.application</string>

    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/your/preferred/workingdirectory</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/node</string>
        <string>your-script-file</string>
    </array>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>

</dict>
</plist>
```

When done, issue this (as root):

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/top-level-domain.your-domain.application.plist
launchctl start top-level-domain.your-domain.application
```

and you are running.

And you will still be running after a restart.

For other options in the plist look at the man page here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html

Comment: What user will this run the service as? Is there a way to set the user?

Answer (score 14):

I am simply using the **daemon** npm module:

```
var daemon = require('daemon');

daemon.daemonize({
    stdout: './log.log'
  , stderr: './log.error.log'
  }
, './node.pid'
, function (err, pid) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error starting daemon: \n', err);
    return process.exit(-1);
  }
  console.log('Daemonized successfully with pid: ' + pid);

  // Your Application Code goes here
});
```

Lately I'm also using [mon(1)](https://github.com/visionmedia/mon) from [TJ Holowaychuk](https://github.com/visionmedia) to start and manage simple node apps.

Answer (score 12):

I use Supervisor for development. It just works. When ever you make changes to a .js file Supervisor automatically restarts your app with those changes loaded.

[Here's a link to its Github page](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor)

Install :

> sudo npm install supervisor -g

You can easily make it watch other extensions with -e. Another command I use often is -i to ignore certain folders.

You can use nohup and supervisor to make your node app run in the background even after you log out.

> sudo nohup supervisor myapp.js &

Comment: I think in practice supervisor is a better option than most of the daemon modules, particularly used in conjunction with a webhook to checkout updates.

Comment: I second this one. If you change PHP files, would you restart Apache or Nginx server? Definitely not. Then why bothering to restart the whole Node.js server even just change one line of code? Though this may not be the best solution, at lease with Supervisor you do not need to worry about the restart process (actually the restart still happen).

Answer (score 7):

Node.js as a background service in **WINDOWS XP**

- Kudos goes to Hacksparrow at: http://www.hacksparrow.com/install-node-js-and-npm-on-windows.html for tutorial installing Node.js + npm for windows.
- Kudos goes to Tatham Oddie at: http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2011/03/16/node-js-on-windows/ for nnsm.exe implementation.

Installation:

1. Install WGET http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm via installer executable
2. Install GIT http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list via installer executable
3. Install NSSM http://nssm.cc/download/?page=download via copying nnsm.exe into %windir%/system32 folder
4. Create c:\node\helloworld.js

   ```
   // http://howtonode.org/hello-node
   var http = require('http');
   var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
       response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
       response.end("Hello World\n");
   });
   server.listen(8000);
   console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
   ```
5. Open command console and type the following (setx only if Resource Kit is installed)

   ```
   C:\node> set path=%PATH%;%CD%
   C:\node> setx path "%PATH%"
   C:\node> set NODE_PATH="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules"
   C:\node> git config --system http.sslcainfo /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt    
   C:\node> git clone --recursive git://github.com/isaacs/npm.git    
   C:\node> cd npm    
   C:\node\npm> node cli.js install npm -gf   
   C:\node> cd ..    
   C:\node> nssm.exe install node-helloworld "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" c:\node\helloworld.js    
   C:\node> net start node-helloworld
   ```
6. A nifty batch goodie is to create c:\node\ServiceMe.cmd

   ```
   @echo off
   nssm.exe install node-%~n1 "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" %~s1
   net start node-%~n1
   pause
   ```

Service Management:

- The services themselves are now accessible via Start-> Run->
  services.msc or via Start->Run-> MSCONFIG-> Services (and check 'Hide
  All Microsoft Services').
- The script will prefix every node made via the batch script with
  'node-'.
- Likewise they can be found in the registry: "**HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\node-xxxx**"

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is probably the best production answer, but for a quick hack doing dev work, I found this:

`nodejs scriptname.js &` didn't work, because nodejs seemed to gobble up the &, and so the thing didn't let me keep using the terminal without scriptname.js dying.

But I put `nodejs scriptname.js` in a .sh file, and
`nohup sh startscriptname.sh &` worked.

Definitely not a production thing, but it solves the "I need to keep using my terminal and don't want to start 5 different terminals" problem.

Answer (score 6):

June 2017 Update:
Solution for Linux: (Red hat).  Previous comments doesn't work for me.
This works for me on Amazon Web Service - Red Hat 7.  Hope this works for somebody out there.

```
A. Create the service file 
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/myapp.service
[Unit]
Description=Your app
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/meantodos/start.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/meantodos/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

```
B. Create a shell file
/home/ec2-root/meantodos/start.sh
#!/bin/sh -
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 8080
npm start

then:
chmod +rx /home/ec2-root/meantodos/start.sh
(to make this file executable)
```

---

```
C. Execute the Following

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start myapp
sudo systemctl status myapp

(If there are no errors, execute below.  Autorun after server restarted.)
chkconfig myapp -add
```

Comment: very Interesting, I am just curious about `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 8080` what it does. Can you give me more details please. I am not sure but I think it redirects traffic from `80` to `8080` which node server listens to, right?

Answer (score 5):

If you are running nodejs in linux server, I think this is the best way.

Create a service script and copy to /etc/init/nodejs.conf

start service: sudo service nodejs start

stop  service: sudo service nodejs stop

Sevice script

```
description "DManager node.js server - Last Update: 2012-08-06"
author      "Pedro Muniz - pedro.muniz@geeklab.com.br"

env USER="nodejs" #you have to create this user 
env APPNAME="nodejs" #you can change the service name
env WORKDIR="/home/<project-home-dir>" #set your project home folder here
env COMMAND="/usr/bin/node <server name>" #app.js ?

# used to be: start on startup
# until we found some mounts weren't ready yet while booting:
start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

pre-start script
    sudo -u $USER echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/$APPNAME.log
end script

script
    # Not sure why $HOME is needed, but we found that it is:
    export HOME="<project-home-dir>"  #set your project home folder here
    export NODE_PATH="<project node_path>"

    #log file, grant permission to nodejs user
    exec start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/$APPNAME.pid --chuid $USER --chdir $WORKDIR --exec $COMMAND >> /var/log/$APPNAME.log 2>&1
end script

post-start script
   # Optionally put a script here that will notifiy you node has (re)started
   # /root/bin/hoptoad.sh "node.js has started!"
end script

pre-stop script
    sudo -u $USER echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/$APPNAME.log
end script
```

Answer (score 3):

use [nssm](http://nssm.cc/download) the best solution for windows, just download [nssm](http://nssm.cc/download), open cmd to nssm directory and type

```
nssm install <service name> <node path> <app.js path> 

eg: nssm install myservice "C:\Program Files\nodejs" "C:\myapp\app.js"
```

this will install a new windows service which will be listed at **services.msc** from there you can start or stop the service, this service will auto start and you can configure to restart if it fails.

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm missing this option in the list of provided answers I'd like to add an eligible option as of 2020: [docker](https://www.docker.com/) or any [equivalent](https://podman.io/) [container](https://cri-o.io/) platform. In addition to ensuring your application is working in a stable environment there are additional security benefits as well as improved portability.

There is docker support for Windows, macOS and most/major Linux distributions. [Installing docker on a supported platform](https://docs.docker.com/install/) is rather straight-forward and well-documented. Setting up a Node.js application is as simple as putting it in a container and running that container while making sure its being restarted after shutdown.

#### Create Container Image

Assuming your application is available in **/home/me/my-app** on that server, create a text file [**Dockerfile**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) in folder **/home/me** with content similar to this one:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
COPY /my-app/ /app/
RUN cd /app && npm ci
CMD ["/app/server.js"]
```

It is creating an image for running LTS version of Node.js under Alpine Linux, copying the application's files into the image and runs `npm ci` to make sure dependencies are matching that runtime context.

Create another file **.dockerignore** in same folder with content

```
**/node_modules
```

This will prevent existing dependencies of your host system from being injected into container as they might not work there. The presented `RUN` command in **Dockerfile** is going to fix that.

Create the image using command like this:

```
docker build -t myapp-as-a-service /home/me
```

The `-t` option is selecting the "name" of built container image. This is used on running containers below.

**Note:** Last parameter is selecting folder containing that Dockerfile instead of the Dockerfile itself. You may pick a different one using option `-f`.

#### Start Container

Use this command for starting the container:

```
docker run -d --restart always -p 80:3000 myapp-as-a-service
```

This command is assuming your app is listening on port 3000 and you want it to be exposed on port 80 of your host.

This is a very limited example for sure, but it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Use pm2 module. [pm2 nodejs module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

Answer (score 2):

To round out the various options suggested, here is one more: the `daemon` command in GNU/Linux, which you can read about here: http://libslack.org/daemon/manpages/daemon.1.html. (apologies if this is already mentioned in one of the comments above).

Answer (score 2):

I am bit late. Simple solution is to execute below two commands in terminal as shown below.

```
nohup node ./server.js &
disown -h %1
```

Then close your ssh session and node program continues to run. Tested on Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 1):

Check out fugue! Apart from launching many workers, you can demonize your node process too!

http://github.com/pgte/fugue

Answer (score 1):

PM2 is a production process manager for Node.js applications with a built-in load balancer. It allows you to keep applications alive forever, to reload them without downtime and to facilitate common system admin tasks.
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Comment: serious memory consumption issues ! go for phusion+ nginx

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that nobody has mentioned [Guvnor](https://github.com/tableflip/guvnor)

I have tried forever, pm2, etc. But, when it comes to solid control and web based performance metrics, I have found [Guvnor](https://github.com/tableflip/guvnor) to be by far the best. Plus, it is also fully opensource.

[image]

**Edit : However, I am not sure if it works on windows. I've only used it on linux.**

Comment: Seems stale as of 2017. Build failing. No code pushes in the last year. Questionable.

Answer (score 1):

has anyone noticed a trivial mistaken of the position of "2>&1" ?

```
2>&1 >> file
```

should be

```
>> file 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

I use tmux for a multiple window/pane development environment on remote hosts. It's really simple to detach and keep the process running in the background. Have a look at [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/)

Answer (score 1):

For people using newer versions of the **daemon** npm module - you need to pass file descriptors instead of strings:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stdoutFd = fs.openSync('output.log', 'a');
var stderrFd = fs.openSync('errors.log', 'a');
require('daemon')({
    stdout: stdoutFd, 
    stderr: stderrFd
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pm2, you can use it with `autorestart` set to `false`:

> $ pm2 ecosystem

This will generate a sample `ecosystem.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      script: './scripts/companies.js',
      autorestart: false,
    },
    {
      script: './scripts/domains.js',
      autorestart: false,
    },
    {
      script: './scripts/technologies.js',
      autorestart: false,
    },
  ],
}
```

> $ pm2 start ecosystem.config.js

Answer (score 1):

I received the following error when using [@mikemaccana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123671/mikemaccana)'s accepted answer on a RHEL 8 AWS EC2 instance: `(code=exited, status=216/GROUP)`

It was due to using the user/group set to: 'nobody'.

Upon googling, it seems that using user/group as 'nobody'/'nogroup' is bad practice for daemons as answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374273/systemd-my-custom-service-exits-with-status-code-216-group) on the unix stack exchange.

It worked great after I set user/group to my actual user and group.

You can enter `whomai` and `groups` to see your available options to fix this.

My service file for a full stack node app with mongodb:

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp
After=mongod.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/myusername/apps/myapp/root/build/server/index.js
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
User=myusername
Group=myusername
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/home/myusername/apps/myapp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: just remember you can;t bind lower ports like 80 443 !!

Answer (score 1):

You can run your node app in background with `&` in unix. Make sure your node app should not have any interactive mode like receive data from input.

```bash
node src/index.js -p 1234 --another-options &
```

Comment: Exactly this does not work for me, because the node seems to have its own handler for hangup, and in that case, running it in background does not help, because it still gets and processes the hangup signal, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64479821/why-hangup-signal-is-caught-even-with-nohup#comment114015475_64479821

Comment: @MatějRačinský Hey! maybe related to your environment. I'm running Linux on my machine at default config. I hadn't any problem about this command. Okay if it doesn't work for you, you will have a lot of approaches. One way is you can use systemd (Linux daemon) or parallel machine 2 machine service (pm2 `npm i -g pm2`)  or nohup, even at Windows you can use some background services like start [read more about start in Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start)

Comment: thanks, in the end the disown worked for me and that works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

This answer is quite late to the party, but I found that the best solution was to write a shell script that used the both the `screen -dmS` and `nohup` commands.

```
screen -dmS newScreenName nohup node myserver.js >> logfile.log
```

I also add the `>> logfile` bit on the end so I can easily save the node `console.log()` statements.

Why did I use a shell script? Well I also added in an if statement that checked to see if the `node myserver.js` process was already running.

That way I was able to create a single command line option that both lets me keep the server going and also restart it when I have made changes, which is very helpful for development.

Comment: I've run into this problem and am pretty new to Linux. How would you do it without screen or nohup?

Answer (score 0):

In case, for local development purpose, you need to start multiple instances of NodeJS app (express, fastify, etc.) then the `concurrently` might be an option. Here is a setup:

### Prerequesites

- Your NodeJS app (express, fastify, etc.) is placed at `/opt/mca/www/mca-backend/app` path.
- Assuming that you are using node v.16 installed via `brew install node@16`

### Setup

1. Install concurrently: `npm install -g concurrently`
2. Create a file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/mca.backend.plist`

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>Label</key>
       <string>mca.backend</string>
       <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
       <array>
           <string>Aqua</string>
           <string>Background</string>
           <string>LoginWindow</string>
           <string>StandardIO</string>
           <string>System</string>
       </array>
       <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
           <string>/usr/local/bin/concurrently</string>
           <string>--names</string>
           <string>dev,prd</string>
           <string>--success</string>
           <string>all</string>
           <string>--kill-others</string>
           <string>--no-color</string>
           <string>MCA_APP_STAGE=dev  node ./server.mjs</string>
           <string>MCA_APP_STAGE=prod node ./server.mjs</string>
       </array>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
       <true/>
       <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
       <dict>
           <key>PATH</key>
           <string>/usr/local/opt/node@16/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin</string>
       </dict>
       <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
       <string>/opt/mca/www/mca-backend/app</string>
       <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
       <string>/opt/mca/www/mca-backend/err.log</string>
       <key>StandardOutPath</key>
       <string>/opt/mca/www/mca-backend/out.log</string>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
3. Load and run: `` launchctl bootstrap gui/`id -u` $HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/mca.backend.plist ``
4. Get a status: `` launchctl print gui/`id -u`/mca.backend ``
5. Stop: `` launchctl kill SIGTERM gui/`id -u`/mca.backend ``
6. Start/Restart: `` launchctl kickstart -k -p  gui/`id -u`/mca.backend ``
7. Unload if not needed anymore: `` launchctl bootout gui/`id -u`/mca.backend ``

**IMPORTANT**: Once you are loaded service with `launchctl bootstrap` any changes you made in file
`~/Library/LaunchAgents/mca.backend.plist` won't be in action until you unload the service (by using `launchctl bootout`)
and then load it again (by using `launchctl bootstrap`).

### Troubleshooting

See launchd logs at: `/private/var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log`