# Nodejs - What does it actually means to deploy a website on a domain and how to do it?

Tags: node.js, deployment, dns, web-deployment

I am a bit new to the deployment of a website. I have a server which is written in `Node.js`. Previously I had been using `Heroku` for deploying my apps without knowing much about deployment. I would like to know how do I deploy my server to create a website which has `.com` at the end of it like `www.example.com` and not `www.example.herokuapp.com`. I think it has something to do with domains (correct me if I am wrong). I would like to know what exactly is a domain and a DNS provider and how to deploy a website in such a way. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I deploy a Node.js application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474842/how-can-i-deploy-a-node-js-application)

Comment: Nope it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask one question to yourself when you hit `www.example.com` in browser how does it load a page?. When you run a website on your laptop it basically runs locally, if you want to access your website over the internet you would require public IP(host or server) accessible over the internet so you can access a webpage using `public IP:port`. But this is not the best option because IP may change in the future and also remembering IP for each application will be difficult. Imagine if you access Facebook, Instagram or any other websites by its IP addresses how difficult and inconvenient would it be? There are a couple of things you should know.

**DNS-> Domain Name system**

> Every host is identified by the IP address but remembering numbers is
>   very difficult for the people and also the IP addresses are not static
>   therefore, a mapping is required to change the domain name to IP
>   address. So DNS is used to convert the domain name of the websites to
>   their numerical IP address.

DNS is a hostname to IP address translation service. DNS is a distributed database implemented in a hierarchy of name servers. It is an application layer protocol for message exchange between clients and servers.

**Name servers**

Domain Name Servers (DNS) are the Internet's equivalent of a phone book. They maintain a directory of domain names and translate them to Internet Protocol (IP) addresses. This is necessary because, although domain names are easy for people to remember, computers or machines, access websites based on IP addresses.

**DNS record**

A domain name, IP address what is the validity?? what is the time to live ?? and all the information related to that domain name.

Once you understand the DNS

1. Host(Deploy) your website to Amazon EC2 or Heroku and obtain Public IP.
2. Buy a domain from domain provider like Godaddy
3. Map domain(ie www.example.com to IP)-> DNS record

Mapping domain to IP may vary platform to platform but the Core principle remains the same. I would suggest you these below link. Try to find differences in both, doing so you will learn along the way

http://www.littlebigextra.com/map-domain-name-amazon-aws-ec2-instance/

https://medium.com/progress-on-ios-development/connecting-an-ec2-instance-with-a-godaddy-domain-e74ff190c233

[image]

Comment: Could you please send me another?

Comment: I would also like to know that is there a way to get a free domain temporarily just to test the deployment as I am doing it for the first time

Comment: you can check here https://www.freenom.com/en/index.html?lang=en