# Where to deploy node.js apps on a Linux server?

Tags: node.js, deployment

I'm running 4 separate Node.js apps on a Linux server with different ports and a proxy in front.

As I'm (right now) the only user in the server, it doesn't matter where I place the apps and how to run them. Currently my apps stay under my home directory (`~/app1/`, `~/app2/`, etc.).

So my question is: where should I place the apps so that they can be shared between multiple users? Is there a standard place similar to `/var/www`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deploy node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681067/how-to-deploy-node-js)

Comment: True, that question solves my problem partly. I will rephrase the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "shared between multiple users"? Do you plan to run each app more than once at the same time?

Comment: Good question. Like with Apache you have `www-data` and `/var/www`. Is there some common, similar practise for node.js?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use https://github.com/visionmedia/deploy to deploy my apps. It will create a `/var/www/productname` directory. Inside that directory you have source, current and shared. The shared directory has the `log` and `pid` files.

I found that a good directory structure so that's what I am using for all my projects.

Comment: Deploy seems really nice, thanks! I will be trying that out soon to see it myself and will get back to you.

Comment: I think `/var/nodejs` is better / safer since `/var/www` was used by web servers like Apache in the past (instead of the new standard `/var/www/html`). Using `/var/www` for Node.js apps could add a risk of having all your server-side source code visible to unauthorized users.

Answer (score 13):

I run Apache in addition to Node.js on the same server, so I don't really like having applications for Apache and Node.js in the same directory. My Apache hosted applications go in the traditional /var/www/ path, and I put my Node.JS applications under /var/node/. This is due to some automation I have setup in both Apache (Dynamic Virtual Hosts) and Node.JS.

More information on my setup and automating Proxy and Apache deployment can be found here: [How to use vhosts alongside node-http-proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368794/how-to-use-vhosts-alongside-node-http-proxy/9370080#9370080)

Comment: Very nice suggestion, thanks! I'll get back to this later after some self-experimentation.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using AWS Elastic beans stack for Node JS application on Linux server, then it should be there in `/var/app/current/` directory

Answer (score 4):

Following the guidelines of the answer here - https://serverfault.com/a/96420
 indicates that /opt/node might be a better places for this, since it'a catchall directory that's reserved for user added program files

Comment: Don't you mean /opt?

Comment: I think the right answer is actually /srv - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35807/recommended-location-of-node-js-applications-in-linux-filesystem

Comment: I feel like apps should be in /opt and files served in /srv and in the Node.js case, it's an app, not shared files. http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES