# How to deliver a node.js program to a client?

Tags: node.js

You've just finished a node.js site. It's a folder with some files and a `my_main_file.js` which handles the requests. The thing works on your machine by running `node my_main_file.js`. How do you deliver this solution to a client, though? Are you supposed to say 'take this folder, install node.js, run that command line and your site will be online'?

Comment: What OS will the site be running on? Make an installer package for that OS that will do the steps necessary to install it as a service.

Comment: @Greg how? Also, as a service? Maybe an executable instead? Not sure which server - the code is multiplatform.

Comment: You want to hear about [node.js deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681067/how-to-deploy-node-js).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. This is quite a bit less complicated than delivering a servable site on other platforms. There are [nodejs installation binaries](http://nodejs.org/download/) for just about every platform and then it's as simple as:

```
$ node site/my_main_file
```

Or maybe there's one more step to install dependencies. Either way, it's about as simple as it gets.