# Deploy node application on an existing EC2 instance rather than elastic beanstalk instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a node.js application on AWS on an existing EC2 instance. Steps http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.sdlc.html describes to deploy on newly created elastic beanstalk instance. How can I reconfigure to add my existing EC2 instance to deploy code on? Or the entire purpose of elastic beanstalk, it to deploy on newly created EB environment?

Comment: You can configure your own environment with an AMI. Not sure if you can make EB deploy to a running E2 instance though. Mainly because EB adds in autoscaling and such, for which it needs to be configured prior with an AMI or default env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk deployment is very specific to the service.

You can conceivable hack the `eb` scripts to make it work for your EC2 instance. You can look at the `AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push` file that the `eb` command creates under the `.git` directory. It's essentially a Ruby script that does the `git push`.

You can could also look at the `eb` script and libraries themselves which are essentially written in Python.

Nevertheless, I recommend to stick to just a plain node.js deployment model that has been answered here on SO on some other posts and Internet blogs. For example: [How do I run a Node.js application as its own process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681067/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-application)

You can also take a look at this blog too (which is referred from the previous SO post)

http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/deploying-nodejs-apps