# Run node server in background

Tags: node.js, server, configuration

I want node server to run in background. I've read that thread: [How do I run a Node.js application as its own process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681067/how-do-i-run-a-node-js-application-as-its-own-process/28542093#28542093)

I get errors:

```
systemd[10948]: myapp_test.service: Failed to determine group credentials: No such process
systemd[10948]: myapp_test.service: Failed at step GROUP spawning /some-directory/index.js: No such process
```

myapp_test.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Something

[Service]
ExecStart=/some-directory/index.js
Restart=always
User=nobody
# Note Debian/Ubuntu uses 'nogroup', RHEL/Fedora uses 'nobody'
Group=nogroup
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=development
WorkingDirectory=/some-directory/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've tried "nobody" as group, I've tried to ommit both user and group but I get this error:

```
systemd[11543]: myapp_test.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
systemd[11543]: myapp_test.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /some-directory/index.js: Permission denied
```

If I go to `some-directory` and type `node index.js` everything works fine (including NODE_ENV=development setting).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be attempting to run a service as a system instance but the service itself defined in as a user-instance(by using User=)

Try copying the .service file to /etc/systemd/user
Run and monitor the system with systemctl --user   options.

To allow the service to remain after the last session of the user is closed look into loginctl here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User