# How does one start a node.js server as a daemon process?

Tags: node.js

In Python Twisted, you have the `twistd` command that helps you with a number of things related to running your application (daemonize it for example).

How do you daemonize a **node.js** server so that it can run even after the current session is closed?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service

Answer (score 99, accepted):

[Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) is answer to your question.

### Install

```
$ curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
$ npm install forever
# Or to install as a terminal command everywhere:
$ npm install -g forever
```

### Usage

**Using Forever from the command line**

```
$ forever start server.js
```

**Using an instance of Forever from Node.js**

```
var forever = require('forever');

  var child = new forever.Forever('your-filename.js', {
    max: 3,
    silent: true,
    args: []
  });

  child.on('exit', this.callback);
  child.start();
```

Comment: Should use -g option to install globally. Might need permissions to do so.

Comment: what happens when you reboot?

Comment: @AlexBrown - you'll need to add the `forever start server.js` to a startup script (e.g. `rc.local`), if you want it to survive reboots.

Comment: I eventually settled on using monit to start and stop the forever process.

Comment: forever is dead, pm2 is the new king. Please dont waste your time on forever. I've just switched and i'm blown away. pm2 can load balance your app on all cores with a simple .. pm2 start app.js -i 0 --name "myapp" ... WOW ... try it and you won't forever look back ... see @Gary Bernitz answer

Answer (score 48):

If you need your process to daemonize itself, not relaying on forever - you can use the **daemonize** module.

```
$ npm install daemonize2
```

Then just write your server file as in example:

```
var daemon = require("daemonize2").setup({
    main: "app.js",
    name: "sampleapp",
    pidfile: "sampleapp.pid"
});

switch (process.argv[2]) {

    case "start":
        daemon.start();
        break;

    case "stop":
        daemon.stop();
        break;

    default:
        console.log("Usage: [start|stop]");
}
```

Mind you, that's rather a low level approach.

Comment: What do you put in app.js? It just exits for me right away.

Comment: What happens on reboot?

Comment: ```case 'restart':
    daemon.on('stopped', () => {
      daemon.start();
    });
    daemon.stop();
    break;```

Answer (score 42):

To start a `systemd` service manager daemon, write a service file. For example, create a file `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service`.

If your `server.js` script is shebanged (`#!/usr/bin/env node` on the first line) and the system can find `node` on the path, this works:

```
[Unit]
Description=myservice-description
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/myservice-location/src/node/server.js --args=here
Restart=always
User=me
Group=group
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myservice-location

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Or, if you don't shebang the file, consider adding the absolute path to the `node` executable that you want to use and prepend that to the `ExecStart=` attribute of the service file.

```
...
ExecStart=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/node ...
...
```

Remember to update the service manager daemon after every change to the myservice.service file.

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then start the service running and enable the service to start at boot.

```
$ systemctl start myservice
$ systemctl enable myservice
```

Comment: where do you put the additional arguments for the server.js in this case?

Answer (score 27):

**UPDATE**: i updated to include the latest from pm2:

for many use cases, using a systemd service is the simplest and most appropriate way to manage a node process. for those that are running numerous node processes or independently-running node microservices in a single environment, pm2 is a more full featured tool.

https://github.com/unitech/pm2

http://pm2.io

- it has a really useful monitoring feature -> pretty 'gui' for command line monitoring of multiple processes with `pm2 monit` or process list with `pm2 list`
- organized Log management -> `pm2 logs`
- other stuff:

  > - Behavior configuration
  > - Source map support
  > - PaaS Compatible
  > - Watch & Reload
  > - Module System
  > - Max memory reload
  > - Cluster Mode
  > - Hot reload
  > - Development workflow
  > - Startup Scripts
  > - Auto completion
  > - Deployment workflow
  > - Keymetrics monitoring
  > - API

Comment: forever is dead, pm2 is king! I've been using forever since forever but just made the switch to pm2. WOW! WOW! WOW! forever runs your app on 1 core, pm2 can do the same OR it can load balance your app on all available cores. WOW! no need for @reboot cron jobs, just do pm2 startup (to start pm2 as a systemd or OS equivalent service) and then pm2 save. now reboot and your apps are still running. You can get the status of a running app with pm2 show. watch is readily available. WOW! unbelievable WOW!

Comment: Setting up pm2 for non-root user in openshift is too much pain.

Answer (score 18):

The simplest approach would just to send the command to the background.

```
$ node server.js &
```

Then you can kill the process at a later time. I usually do the following:

```
$ killall node
```

**Note**: I'm running OS X.

Comment: Note that this will not work if you log out of your terminal/ssh session. The full solution for that is nohup node server.js >/dev/null 2>&1 &

Comment: @MichaelDillon Why do you think redirecting outputs to `/dev/null` should be included in the full solution?

Answer (score 11):

You can try:

```
$ nohup node server.js &
```

It work for me on Mac and Linux.

The output will be in the `./nohup.out` file

But I still recommend you use `pm2` or `forever`, because they are easily used for restarting, stopping and logging.

Answer (score 3):

There are more advanced general-purpose runners, such as `monit` and `runit`.

Answer (score 1):

## 2022 - PM2

There is a better and one of the most popular solutions for that and it's called `pm2` ([npm package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)).

To run one or multiple `Node.js` servers you need to install it: `npm install pm2 -g`

To run: `pm2 start app.js`

To stop: `pm2 stop nameOfAppFromList`

---

You can also list your running apps  `pm2 list`

To check logs of a specific one, run `pm2 logs nameOfAppFromList`

Answer (score 0):

For the background on the normal way to daemonise on a POSIX system you can search for the C method.

I have not seen enough methods in the node.js API to allow it to be done the C way by hand. However, when using child_process, you can have node.js do it for you:

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

I consider this a potential waste of time because there's a good chance your system provides the same.

For example:

http://libslack.org/daemon/manpages/daemon.1.html

If you want something portable (cross platform) the other posts offer solutions that might suffice.