# Running Forever in Ansible Provision Never Fires or Always Hangs

Tags: node.js, ansible, forever

I've come across a problem with Anisble hanging when trying to start a `forever` process on an Ansible node.  I have a very simple API server I'm creating in vagrant and provisioning with Ansible like so:

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes

  roles:
    - Stouts.nodejs
    - Stouts.mongodb

  tasks:
    - name: Install Make Dependencies
      apt: name={{ item }} state=present
      with_items:
        - gcc
        - make
        - build-essential

    - name: Run NPM Update
      shell: /usr/bin/npm update

    - name: Create MongoDB Database Folder
      shell: /bin/mkdir -p /data/db
      notify:
        - mongodb restart

    - name: Generate Dummy Data
      command: /usr/bin/node /vagrant/dataGen.js

    - name: "Install forever (to run Node.js app)."
      npm: name=forever global=yes state=latest

    - name: "Check list of Node.js apps running."
      command: /usr/bin/forever list
      register: forever_list
      changed_when: false

    - name: "Start example Node.js app."
      command: /usr/bin/forever start /vagrant/server.js
      when: "forever_list.stdout.find('/vagrant/server.js') == -1"
```

But even though Ansible acts like everything is fine, no forever process is started.  When I change a few lines to remove the `when:` statement and force it to run, Ansible just hands, possibly running the forever process (forever, I presume) but not launching the VM to where I can interact with it.

I've referenced essentially two points online; the [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919222/ansible-hangs-when-starting-node-js-server) [sources](https://servercheck.in/blog/start-nodejs-app-with-forever-and-ansible) I can find.

Comment: Did you try to run it manually in the vm? Just to know if it's a problem with `ansible` or with `forever` itself

Comment: your question misses the output of variable `forever_list.stdout` to be useful

Comment: I'd put `- debug: var= forever_list.stdout` to check

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the comments the variable content needs to be included in your question for anyone to provide a correct answer but to overcome this I suggest you can do it like so:

```
    - name: "Check list of Node.js apps running."
      command: /usr/bin/forever list|grep '/vagrant/server.js'|wc -l
      register: forever_list
      changed_when: false

    - name: "Start example Node.js app."
      command: /usr/bin/forever start /vagrant/server.js
      when: forever_list.stdout == "0"
```

which should prevent ansible from starting the JS app if it's already running.