# How to use the Ansible Shell module on Linux to start Node.js server in the background?

Tags: node.js, linux, ansible

If I ran the `nohup node /tmp/test-app/index.js > /tmp/test-app/nohup.out 2>&1 &` command in my Linux console, it works. It starts the node.js server in the background and I am able to see the running process using the command `ps aux | grep node`.

However, if I ran the exact same command as a task in my Playbook, the Playbook executes and the task is marked as `changed`, but it actually doesn't start the node server.

I have checked `/var/log/messages` and have verbose logged the Playbook execution with `-vvv`. The command seems to be going to the Linux console, but the node server doesn't seem to start from the Playbook (but it does start if just execute the command directly on the console.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Here's the Playbook task:

```
---
- name: Test app 
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

  vars:
    tmp_dir: '/tmp/test-app'

  tasks:
    - name: Start the demo app in the background
      shell: 'nohup node /tmp/test-app/index.js > /tmp/test-app/nohup.out 2>&1 &'
      args:
        chdir: '{{tmp_dir}}'
```

Comment: I think if you want to start a service like that you should create a systemd [service unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html) and start it using ansible's `service` module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21385202/1417694

Comment: @Squashman That answer is from 2014 (10 years ago). Are you sure that's still the right way? What's wrong with the `nohup` method I am doing?