# Is there any way to make electron execute a nodejs file server in the background when build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, electron

I'm having problems with an electron app that makes calls to an API using a server build with express and *Node.Js*. The problem is that when i build the APP i can't find a way of executing the server in the background. If you know anything please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903570/how-does-one-start-a-node-js-server-as-a-daemon-process

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code looks like but I assume you have something like this:

```
function createWindow () {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
    ...
 });
```

What you could do is have `nodeIntegration: true` and then you could include the server files run in your index.html file. `<script src=fileServer.js></script>`. This allows script files to use node specific functions such as `require('express')` or something along those lines.

Again I can't help much more because I don't know what your code looks like.