# How to automatically start a NodeJs Express server when EC2 starts

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, bash, amazon-ec2, ec2-userdata

I have an EC2 instance Linux/UNIX, t2.micro. Al there is in there is a NodeJs Express server. If I cd ./project-folder-name and then run "npm run server" it starts a server which can accept API requests.
I use this server only 15 minutes a day so I am thinking to have it in a schedule to stop/start only for 1 hour.
I got the code that starts and stops it but I don't know how to make the EC2 to start the Express server (go to the path and run "npm run server") after the EC2 is restarted.
Note: No need to worry about pulling the project from gitlab or updating dependencies (npm install or any other command). Literally, all I want it is to get to the folder and run "npm run server", which is a script on my package.json file

I appreciate if someone can give me some instructions on how to do that.

Comment: Check different solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903570/how-does-one-start-a-node-js-server-as-a-daemon-process

Comment: None of them offers a solution to my problem. I know how to run my server continuously. The challenge is to restart the app (running "npm run server") after the EC2 restarts.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of custom systemd service. Creating a custom systemd service in Ubuntu enables users to start, stop, and manage custom background processes effectively.

create a bash script file with the required commands to run your node application.

in `my_node_app.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Custom script to node application
cd /path/to/node/app/folder
npm install
npm run server
```

make the script executable `chmod +x /path/to/script/my_node_app.sh`

Create a new unit file at `/etc/systemd/system/my_node_app.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=My Custom Service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/script/my_node_app.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Execute the following commands to `reload`, `enable` and `start` the service

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable my_node_app.service
systemctl start my_node_app.service
```

After starting the services every time instance reboot this service will run the script.