# nohup VERBOSE=1 perl script.pl

Tags: shell, nohup

I have a perl script for which ENV variables can be set to direct specific outputs
e.g. $debug, $verbose, $develop etc

Usually I run these from the command line

```
$ VERBOSE=1 perl myperlscript.pl params
```

I now want to run them using nohup. Using the command line

```
$ nohup VERBOSE=1 perl myperlscript.pl params
```

is clearly not right, as the attempt to set ENV{VERBOSE} is interpreted as a param to nohup & I get the msg

nohup: failed to run command `VERBOSE=1': No such file or directory

What IS the correct syntax here? I'm trying to run this on a linux box.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Set the environment variable before calling `nohup`, and it will be preserved when `nohup` exec()s (replaces itself with) `perl`.

```
$ VERBOSE=1 nohup perl myscript.pl params ...
```

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what the `env` command is for:

```
$ env VAR1=VAL1 VAR2=VAL2 nohup perl myperlscript.pl params &
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine all commands into shell script and run it like that:
nohup /path/to/script.sh

Or you could use export:
export VERBOSE=1
And then:
nohup perl myperlscript.pl params