# Java process run using fab not picking the environment variable exported in .bashrc

Tags: java, python-2.7, fabric

I'm using fabric to deploy an application. I run the java application using the below command:

```
java -jar appname.jar
```

This application depends on some environment variables set in .bashrc. So I run the application using the below fab command.

```
run("source $HOME/.bashrc && nohup java -jar seyren.jar")
```

The process runs. However the environment variable needed by the process is not available.

When I run the same command as below from the command line it works

```
nohup java -jar seyren.jar
```

Can you please let me know what mistake I'm making while using Fab?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825460/nohup-verbose-1-perl-script-pl) help you?

Comment: No. It does not answer my question. The environment variables are already set using the source $HOME/.bashrc. But it does not get picked up even after that!