# How to write first application in Node.js in Windows Environment?

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, web

I have downloaded `Node.js` from their site in my windows xp os. I have installed it through the microsoft installer. I didn't know how to write my first application, where to save them and how to execute them in Windows. I have got a `node.js` command prompt but I can't use it.
I have searched a lot but there is only instruction for `linux` and `mac`. I didn't find any suitable `tutorial` or example that I can start a node application from scratch.

If anybody can put some `documentation` or `steps` or any such tutorial where I can get help of this, it will be great for me.

Comment: I imagine if you have a node.js command prompt then it would be as simple as creating a js based file in a directory, then navigating to that directory using the node.js command prompt and then typing node <your_script_name>.

Comment: ok I am trying it @ZeSimon

Comment: If you search Google exactly for `node.js server windows`, there's several articles on how to run it with a server. Note, however, that most of what I saw reference IIS, which I have no idea if and how you can get that installed. But you need a server running that can handle sending requests to your node.js runtime. Apache, nginx, lighthttp, and IIS are most typical (Tomcat?).

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](http://thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/4/23/getting-started-with-node-js-on-windows), using node.js to create a server. Seems interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [this blog entry](http://thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/4/23/getting-started-with-node-js-on-windows) by Eric, it is ridiculously easy to get a node.js server setup and responding to requests on `127.0.0.1:#port#`.

Really easy. I just did it all in... Longer than write this text.

1. Download an OS-appropriate node.js<sup>**1**</sup>: http://nodejs.org/
2. Now, create a `.txt` (plaintext) file in the same folder as your `node.exe` and rename that to `server.js`.
3. Put this Javascript in that file:

   ```
   var http = require('http');

   http.createServer(function (request, response) {
       console.log('request starting...');

       response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

       var html = '<p>Hello World!</p>';

       response.end(html, 'utf-8');
   }).listen(8125);

   console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8125/');
   ```
4. Open a `cmd.exe` and `cd c:\path\to\the\node\executable`, where `node.exe` resides.
5. From there, run:

   ```
   node server.js
   ```

   You should see it say:

   ```
   Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8125
   ```
6. Open a browser and put `http://127.0.0.1:8125/` in the address bar.

   You should see it say:

   ```
   Hello World!
   ```

That's it. That's pretty easy. The proverbial `Hello World!` in 15 seconds or less. Now how to get it to parse a Javascript file and return that output instead of simple HTML...

---

<sub><sup>**1.**</sup> Note, I got the executable, `node.exe`, made a folder somewhere, put the executable in that folder. No installer. Works like a charm.</sub>

Comment: Its now running. But When I closed the command prompt. Server is not running anymore. Is there any way to run it altime?

Comment: Run it as a service. See the answers for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547974/how-to-install-node-js-as-windows-service).

Comment: @JaredFarrish - regarding #4, I added node path in system variables of my Windows Server 2008 R2 and now its working from anywhere by passing this from cmd.exe _node.exe "C:\nodejs-stuff\Server.js"_

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new way develop node.js app with Windows Environments and Visual Studio >= 2012
https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.