# Best way to start a Node.js file at Windows startup

Tags: windows, node.js, startup

What is the best way to startup a node.js script on Windows Startup?

Preferred freeware or Open Source.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install node.js as windows service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547974/how-to-install-node-js-as-windows-service)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, create "`.bat` file like that "`node my_script.js`" and add that file to "Autostart" / "Startup" directory.

Comment: It would help if you could elaborate on "Autostart" / "Startup"  directory path.

Answer (score 6):

You can find the `auto startup` path as these steps:
 1. keydown, `win + r`
 2. input `shell:startup`, key `enter`
Do what you can see~