# Deploy nodejs in Windows environment

Tags: windows, node.js, deployment

I am trying to deploy nodejs in a windows environment. As far as I can see nodejs is just a standard application run through the command-line. However running it that way is not very practical in a server environment. Is there a way to run it as a windows service, so you get all the benefits of controlling the execution as you have with other services? I found similar forum entries about this subject, however they are all related to running nodejs in a linux environment, how would you go about doing this in a window environment?

Comment: What's not practical?

Comment: It's not practical, since it requires you to constantly be logged into the server in a session with a command line, and if the server is rebooted or nodejs crashes, you need to rerun the command, so you need to constantly monitor it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install node.js as windows service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547974/how-to-install-node-js-as-windows-service)

Comment: You might want to read this, http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx It basically solves all the problems you mentioned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nodejs application is not like mongodb, redis, nginx ... It's not supposed to run as an os service.

As a best practice, people usually use a process management tool like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to run production nodejs applications. You can give it a try by creating a `deploy.sh` or `deploy.bat` as an execution file which trigger `pm2` command to start or restart the application.

Comment: How about the MongoDB that goes along with the Node.js server ?