# Start Node Js Server Automatically on Pc Start Up

Tags: node.js, cmd, startup

I have a Node Server.

And I want that my Node Server starts automatically when my Pc Starts.

Right Now I am doing this Manually.

Like this:

1) First I open Command Prompt.

2) Than I Type

```
cd node
```

3) Thank I type

```
node server.js
```

I want these 3 Step to perform automatically when my Pc starts.

Any solution please ?

Comment: Possibly this should be moved over to http://superuser.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install node.js as windows service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547974/how-to-install-node-js-as-windows-service)

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be to write a .bat script that you launch on startup.

---

Another option, that I personally would have used, is [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) (or other modules like it) to create a Windows Service, running it in the background. You can specify if you want your Service to start automatically in the background or not when Windows starts.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple .bat script and add the script [as described here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770556.aspx)
Assuming you mean Windows (cmd), this should work for you. Also it might be a good idea to specify an absolute path for the node executable, and/or file.