# What are the different ways to run a node.js file indefinitely in windows server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduled-tasks, server

I know we can run a node.js file in windows via the command prompt like below

```
cd c:\wamp\www\myfolder
c:\wamp\www\myfolder>node testing.js
```

My question is, How can I automate this file to run indefinitely for every 10 second or 1 minute in windows?

As of now I have created a scheduler in windows system which is running every 1 minute to execute my js file. I have created a .bat file with required commands and put it in the scheduler. So it is running perfectly. I want to know, are there any other best solutions available?

One more question I have is, every time I run "node testing.js" command, does node js will create a new server instance or will it use the same / old instance which is created earlier. What is the mechanism behind that.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I automate this file to run indefinitely for every 10 second or 1 minute in windows?

You can use [Windows' task scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) to do that. It has both a UI and an [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Alternately, rather than running every 10 seconds, you might [run it as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547974/how-to-install-node-js-as-windows-service).

Comment: Thanks T.J. I have already created the windows scheduler, I have to look at the run it as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at foreverjs

https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

I found it very flexible and reliable.

Comment: Looks like, this forever js works for linux, is it available for windows also?

Comment: I use it under linux and mac, it is a node application therefore it should also work with windows. EDIT: According to the github issue track it should work in actual version under windows.