# nodejs server on windows disaster recovery

Tags: node.js, windows, rest, disaster-recovery, edge.js

Hello I'm developing a web api that need to communicate with software the is installed on a windows machine.
I considering to create a node server that listen to the request and then communicate with the software using the C# api (using edge.js).
My main question is how I can make a node.js app work on the background and restart in case of disaster. I always used the node.js on web server and I don't know how it behaves on normal machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) tool, or by [installing node as a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547974/how-to-install-node-js-as-windows-service).

See which solution suits you best.