# Window server deploy PHP and NODE together

Tags: php, node.js, iis, windows-services

I have a windows Server and installed IIS, on IIS php is installed.
I have a Node js application I want deploy it to a directory like
main application that is on php is accessible on www.test.com
new Node application path would be www.test.com/new/
anyone know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ways how to run node.js with IIS (ARR or  iisnode project). I prefer to do that with ARR. You need to follow this steps:

1. You need to install [ARR module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) and [Rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for IIS
2. In IIS manager you should enable reverse proxy

   2.1. On server node click "Application Request Routing Cache"

   2.2. Click "Server proxy settings" and click "Enable proxy", then "Apply"
3. Run your node.js application with the console or [like win service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18584217/1954204) with any different port. For example, it is port 3000
4. In `web.config` of application `www.test.com` add this rewrite rule:

   ```
   <rule name="rewrite new to node.js" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="^new(.*)" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000{R:1}" />
   </rule>
   ```
5. Try to make a call to `www.test.com/new/`

PS: You might have problems with links to your assets/images. Make sure that you using correct URL