# How to Use CasperJS in node.js?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I would like to use CasperJS in node.js.

I have referred to the following URL's to use CasperJS in node.js:

- https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node
- http://casperjs.org/index.html#faq-executable

With the help of the above URLs I have written the following code:

```
//DISPLAY=:0 node test2.js
var phantom = require('phantom');
console.log('Hello, world!');
phantom.create(function (ph) {
    ph.casperPath = '/opt/libs/casperjs'
    ph.injectJs('/opt/libs/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js');
    var casper = require('casper').create();
    casper.start('http://google.fr/');

    casper.thenEvaluate(function (term) {
        document.querySelector('input[name="q"]').setAttribute('value', term);
        document.querySelector('form[name="f"]').submit();
    }, {
        term: 'CasperJS'
    });

    casper.then(function () {
        // Click on 1st result link
        this.click('h3.r a');
    });

    casper.then(function () {
        console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
    });

    casper.run();
});
```

---

When I run this code, I got the following error:

*ERROR MSG:*

```
tz@tz-ubuntu:/opt/workspaces/TestPhantomjs$ DISPLAY=:0 node test2.js 
Hello, world!
Error: Cannot find module 'casper'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at /opt/workspaces/TestPhantomjs/test2.js:6:14
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/workspaces/TestPhantomjs/node_modules/phantom/phantom.js:82:43)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/opt/workspaces/TestPhantomjs/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/index.js:215:30)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at handleMethods (/opt/workspaces/TestPhantomjs/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode-protocol/index.js:138:14)
    at EventEmitter.handle (/opt/workspaces/TestPhantomjs/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode-protocol/index.js:98:13)
phantom stdout: Unable to load casper environment: Error: Failed to resolve module fs, tried fs
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/group/casperjs/browse_thread/thread/641e9e6dff50fb0a/e67aaef5ab4ec918?hl=zh-CN#e67aaef5ab4ec918

Nicolas Perriault
2012/2/27 天猪 蓝虫. :

> I wan to use casperjs in nodejs. 
>   and refs to: 
>   https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node and 
>   http://casperjs.org/index.html#faq-executable
>
> You can't run CasperJS that way; QtWebKit and V8 don't share the same 
>   js environment (and event loop), so your node.js app won't be able to 
>   load and use a CasperJS module.   You have to run your CasperJS script
>   separately using a subprocess call,  [like this one on github](https://github.com/n1k0/nodetunes/blob/master/Cakefile#L41). I
>   don't  plan to make CasperJS compatible with phantomjs-node because it
>   uses  `alert()`-based dirty hacks I'm not easy with.
>
> Cheers, 
>   --  Nicolas Perriault

Answer (score 25):

You can use [SpookyJS](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS) to drive CasperJS from Node.

Comment: yup.. i can't get their [hello world](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/issues/39) example to work!

Comment: Lots of bugs in that module. It doesn't even install cleanly from npm.

Comment: I gave up trying to get SpookyJS to work and did this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459097/how-to-use-casperjs-in-node-js/18243793#18243793

Comment: Spooky is correctly working for me. I made a little gist for people who want to play with it in Meteor. https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/056d9c930346294d844d

Comment: Looks inactive to me to: last commit is a year ago, they have unusual imports and don't use semver.

Comment: It took a while, but I got Spooky to work. Follow instructions and see: https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS/issues/71#issuecomment-267704986

Answer (score 17):

[CasperJS includes a web server to talk to the outside world](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/method/listen.html). Node (using `request`, `superagent` etc) can now talk to casper over HTTP.

In `scraper.js`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env casperjs

// I AM NOT NODEJS
// I AM CASPER JS
// I RUN IN QTWEBKIT, NOT V8

var casper = require('casper').create();
var server = require('webserver').create();
var ipAndPort = '127.0.0.1:8585';

server.listen(ipAndPort, function(request, response) {

    casper.start('https://connect.data.com/login');
    casper.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36");
    casper.then(function(){
        // lots of code here, and a few more cassper.then()s
    });

    casper.run(function(){
        console.log('\n\nFinished')
        response.statusCode = 200;
        var body = JSON.stringify({
            phoneNumber: '1800-YOLO-SWAG'
        })

        response.write(body);
        response.close();
    });
});
```

You can now run `scraper.js` as a web server:

```
chmod +x scraper.js
./scraper.js
```

You should [run it as a Linux service just like you would for a node app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service/29042953#29042953).

Comment: **This is the simplest, cleanest answer**. In it's original form it wasn't clear what you were doing (particularly mentioning PHP) so I've edited a bit, added my own code as an example, and linked to the official docs, but you deserve all the karma: you've just saved me a bunch of work 

Comment: what does casper.start() do?  their docs suck.  What does it return?  the docs on the CasperJS site doesn't tell what it's actually doing under the hood and I'm not about to go sifting through the CasperJS core code

Comment: @WTF what `casper.start()` does is at http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#start

Comment: Thanks for answer! But when casperjs finished its work after casper.run, script closing itself automatically. That's why server is closed and I can't send other requests without starting script from command line. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

One solution (which worked for me) is to start and stop your server on a per-test basis. For example, I have a `runtests.coffee` which looks like:

```
http = require 'http'
glob = require 'glob'
spawn = require('child_process').spawn

db = require './db' # Contains all database stuff.
webapp = require './webapp' # Contains all of the Express stuff.

db.connect 'test' # Connects to the db server and creates an empty test db.
server = http.createServer webapp.makeApp()
server.listen 0, ->
    port = server.address().port
    process.env.URL = "http://localhost:#{ port }"
    glob 'tests/*', (err, filenames) ->
        child = spawn 'casperjs', ['test'].concat(filenames)
        child.stdout.on 'data', (msg) -> process.stdout.write msg
        child.stderr.on 'data', (msg) -> process.stderr.write msg
        child.on 'exit', (code) ->
            db.disconnect() # Drops the test db.
            server.close()
            process.exit code
```

And my CasperJS tests in `tests/` look like:

```
URL = require('system').env.URL # Note, Casper code here, not Node.

casper.test.begin 'Test something', 1, (test) ->
    casper.start "#{ URL }/welcome"
    casper.then ->
        test.assertHttpStatus 200
        # ....
    casper.run ->
        test.done()
```

Comment: Hi paid nerd, this looks like a great solution for a set up I am looking to solve. I am a bit fresh to node and casperjs, do you have a Gist or something for a more elaborate view on this?

Comment: @gumaflux Unfortunately, I can't share the rest of the code. If you have a specific clarification I can do my best to answer it.

Comment: @a paid nerd: that's understandable,  my question was on a high level how you encapsulated the functionality in webapp and db, but I fleshed it out in code and it all made sense. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @gumaflux Ah, I see now one part not in the above: When the web server starts in test mode it adds a bunch of test-only routes, such as `/login-as-user` or `/delete-user`, so that I can setup state from the casper tests.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means that your script can't find Casper; have you checked the path and made sure that

```
/opt/libs/casperjs
```

and:

```
/opt/libs/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js
```

Are accessible by a website user ? considering the location it's probably not likely.
/opt is a unix path, but the website will be looking in {websiterootpath}/opt.

I'd create a subfolder 'casperjs' in the root folder of your website and copy the contents of

```
/opt/libs/casperjs
```

To there.
Then change your paths from

```
/opt/libs/casperjs
```

To

```
/casperjs
```

Comment: yes,the path is right. and I run the test code in bash shell.I think nodejs's require don't know how to find casper but don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run casper by node cron job too,
here's my solution

in casper.js echo your response:

```
casper.then(function() {
    var comments = this.evaluate(getComments);
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(comments));
})
```

use node-cmd in node file casper_wrapper.js:

```
var cmd = require('node-cmd');

module.exports = function(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        cmd.get(
            'casperjs casper.js ' + url, // casper takes args to run the script
            function(err, data, stderr){
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                resolve(obj);
            }
        );
    });
}
```