# casperjs on my code not in separate js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, casperjs

I need to use casperjs to solve cloudflare under attack http get request issue,
to call Rest api from client app, I win to call it in casperjs module,
but it runs from command line when put code in separate js file, and use it like:

```
> casperjs sample.js
```

now I need to use it in my code to call http request,
such as in angularjs, I use ionic framework,
I cannot import library like this: `var casper = require('./lib/casperjs').create();`

that is /casperjs is a folder inside ./lib/ folder, I get it from this command:

```
npm install casperjs
```

I face this error: 
Error: Module name "lib/casperjs" has not been loaded yet for context

now how to fix this to gets work on my code, what is needed ?

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

Comment: I don't know how it solve

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446844/dynamic-require-in-requirejs-getting-module-name-has-not-been-loaded-yet-for-c

Comment: I cannot understand how to solve, I try, but I cannot win

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459097/how-to-use-casperjs-in-node-js