# NodeJS Express Site

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, express

I have moved my express site on to a free tier Amazon EC2 Server.

I want to have the server live however the only way I know how to run the site is via SSH (via Putty), although the problem with this is that as soon as Putty closes the site is down.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I may be wrong, because I'm fairly new to node.js and express, but I think most people use nginx or some web server to host node.js in.  Are you doing this? [SO Post about setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-and-now)

Comment: Node.js is capable of serving HTTP content on its own, so running nginx or apache and proxying to node.js isn't necessary (although depending on your architecture is advisable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're (probably) having is that you're not running it as a background process.
The correct solution is to convert the process to a daemon, or something similar.

See: [Node.js as a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service) and https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

Comment: Thanks I did the npm install forever and was VERY! simple to set up thanks