# Want to Run Bot on Server 24/7

Tags: node.js, server-side, bots

I made a bot (https://github.com/JBader89/PlugBot) for a social music site, and I'd like to have it running 24/7. I used node.js to create and run it, so I was wondering if there's a way to use node.js to make it run continually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is already is answered in other thread [Node.js as a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service). You can use [Forever](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever), This is pretty good to re spawn server on event of unexpected behavior.

Comment: I want to run javascript 24/7 online so that it can process some data. Is there any way to do that?
I have a webpage which calls google Map api, processes data and store that to db. I want to keep it running all the time

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) or [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) to make a node.js service and make sure it runs continuously. There are simpler ways to make sure that the node.js process keeps running after you are logged out, but these tools are specifically designed for running node.js services.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use repl.it and uptime robot. its 100% free, and its easier to transfer code. it also has dark mode now!

Comment: This couldn't be more off-topic