# running cURL and node server simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I'm learning Node JS. Going through node js in action, came to an example where cURL was being used as http client. Once the server started, I can't call cURL commands in cmd. How do I run them simultaneously ?

Comment: Can't you just open another cmd...?

Comment: I didn't know that. Sorry and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open a second command line prompt. If you are connecting to a server remotely you could open a second connection. You might also want to take a look at this: [Node.js as a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service)