# nodejs server run on remote

Tags: node.js, socket.io, server

I wasn't quite sure what to call this question but here i go:

i have a `remote server` where i have installed `node.js` now normally this would be how i start the server:

```
ssh root@ip
cd /var/www/mydomain/server
nodejs server.js
```

This works without any issues however what happens when i close down the terminal? How can i make sure that the server doesn't just stop. And how can i control it after i have started it (for instance restarting / stopping it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js as a background service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of solutions here, but maybe the most easy to start with is using `forever`.

[Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) is a npm module that keep your app running and restarts it if it crashes.

Also there are more advanced solutions, like using [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), which I recommend, but first take a look at forever.