# Re-reaching the console with working application on ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ssh, process, terminal, connection

I currently connected to a ubuntu server by ssh.I wrote an activated a nodejs server and currently running on shell and can be reached by internet.
My question If I close my ssh window will this process be terminated on server .
if not next time when i connect to the server how i can reach this working terminal again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description on its [website](https://nodejs.org/), there is no mention of the server detaching from the controlling terminal or suppressing `SIGHUP`. 
So yes - you will probably terminate your server.

This has been discussed before, in [Node.js as a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service), which suggests the usual solutions:

- use [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) (and then you lose direct control over the server if you log out)
- run the server within [screen(1)](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html), which allows you to attach to that screen session when you log in again.

If your remote host does not have screen, of course that limits your options.  However, if you have full control over the server, you should be able to install `screen` as follows

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

`screen` is simple enough to use (but there is much documentation).  For the use which you would make, you would do

```
screen
```

to run a session, and in the resulting shell session, run your server.  To detach, type <kbd>control A</kbd>.  To reattach, I would use

```
screen -x
```