# How to I run a process on a digital ocean droplet and keep it running when I log out?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I am new to nodejs and digital ocean. I set up a digital ocean droplet and I want to run a node server on my droplet forever. So I ssh into the droplet (Ubuntu) and run node myNodeProgram.js. It works great for a few minutes but whenever the connection drops the node process stops running.

So how do I make it always run?

Comment: look up "run node as a daemon"

Comment: One of my favorite things about Digital Ocean is [their excellent tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) :-)

Comment: Thanks. I looked that up and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service

Answer (score 0):

Install pm2 nodejs process manager.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)