# Code Deploy ApplicationStart gets stuck on pending using node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Hi I'm new to using Code Deploy. I am trying to launch a node application. I have setup.sh, start.sh and app.js in my root directory.

This is my appspec.yml file

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
 - source: /
   destination: /
hooks:
  Install:
    - location: setup.sh
      timeout: 3600
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: start.sh
      timeout: 3600
```

setup.sh

```
yum -y install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
npm install
```

start.sh

```
node /app.js
```

app.js (just a basic dummy server)

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/",function(req,res) {
    res.send("Hello world")
})


var server = app.listen(8080,function() {
    console.log("Listening at " + server.address().address + ": " + server.address().port);
});
```

The Install step successfully completes, but Code Deploy gets stuck on pending when it does the ApplicationStart step.

I'm pretty sure it's because the app.js program runs continously, so how is CodeDeploy supposed to know that it's working and move on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `node /app.js` does not run in background but in foreground, therefor the start.sh script is never finished.

See this thread for more info about running node in background [Node.js as a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service)

Answer (score 5):

The CodeDeploy agent is waiting for the script it launched to return an exit code and to close `stdout` and `stderr`. To start a process in the background and detach it from the host agent so it can run as a daemon, try:

```
node /app.js > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &
```

Note: you'll want to modify your program to write to a log file instead of the console, since daemons usually don't have a console to write to (as it is in this version).

See the official docs here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-long-running-processes

Comment: How do we kill this process created by this command ? It seems to respawn into a new process(different PID) in the ApplicationStop script. I've tried `fuser -k 3000/tcp`, `lsof -P | grep ':3000' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9` every time a new process is created. Thanks in advance.

Comment: start.sh should look like `npm start > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null & echo $! > node.pid`, basically add `echo $! > node.pid` to the end.

Also make stop.sh which will kill that pid `if [ -f node.pid ]; then
 kill `cat node.pid`
fi`