# Schedule job stopping in background

Tags: node.js, nohup

After logging in to a remote server. I use `nohup` command to run a scheduler job 
which runs using the `node-schedule` module. So basically a nodejs file contains the code for scheduling the job which has to run every 12 hours. I logout and then login but it stops sometimes. Can anyone suggest what might be happening ? 
Why is it getting stopped ? I want to debug, but then I have no clue as to, why is it stopping ?

Comment: Did you check the content of the file `nohup.out`? Did you check if the scheduler is still running (`ps ax | grep <name of program>`)?

Comment: yes when I do `ps -ef | grep node` , it doesn't show the process

Comment: The `nohup` command creates a file `nohup.out` in the directory where you execute it. All the output from the program is redirected into that file. So if node crashed due to an exception, the exception should be logged in the file.

Comment: yeah , I checked that out the nohup.out is empty, because it should have ran next at 12:00.

Comment: And there are no exceptions from node

Comment: If your script really works when running it without `nohup`, then I have no further clue what could be wrong. One workaround might be to use cron instead for scheduling, the other might be to use one of the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service).

Comment: have you explored using forever ?

Comment: Yeah I am checking for other solutions.