# How to run angular 2 app in background

Tags: node.js, npm, angular, gulp, lite-server

i have  already tried following solution but it is not working.

```
sudo forever start -c "npm start" ./
```

and package.json file is something like this, look at the start command: (this is not full package.json)

```
"name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run gulp\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find any solution ?? I have spend 2 hours in googling.

Comment: yes it is angular-cli, using that you can deploy your angular 2 app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found [angular-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli), which helps me to deploy my angular 2 app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to piggyback off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042953/3199310), most importantly this part:

> nearly every Linux distro comes with systemd, which means
>   forever, monit, etc are no longer necessary - your OS already handles
>   these tasks.

You can configure a service file for angular2-quickstart that your OS's systemd can use to start up a background process for your application. [Here](https://certsimple.com/blog/deploy-node-on-linux) is an article on deploying applications in Linux environments that can help.