# Forever "npm start" on server

Tags: angular, npm, forever

I am trying to run an angular2 test app on server, it works fine on local machine   with NPM start as in my package json:

```
"start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ".
```

How can i run `npm start` on server via forever? I tried `forever start -c "npm start" /path/to/app/dir/` but it doesn't work.

Comment: currently looking into => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362765/how-to-run-angular-2-app-in-background

Answer (score 0):

in the end just did NPM install on server and seemed to work straight out of box There was slight issue with relative paths but by changing the folder on server resolved the issue. i guuess 'npm start' not required in the end..Thanks