# nohup node service using cron job on CentOS 7

Tags: node.js, bash, cron, nohup

I want to run nohup node service using cron job on CentOS 7. For this I created a file /home/guest/start_indexjs mentioned below

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -f "index.js" >/dev/null; then
   echo "index.js is Running."
else
   echo "index.js is Stopped."
   nohup node /root/demo/index.js > /root/index-nohup.log &
fi
```

I login with ssh root and run following command:

```
cd /home/guest/
chown root start_indexjs
chgrp -R root start_indexjs
chmod +x start_indexjs
```

I want to run `/home/guest/start_indexjs` every 1 minute. For this I added the following line into `/etc/crontab`:

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/guest/start_indexjs > /var/log/start_indexjs.log
```

I created a `/var/log/start_indexjs.log` with following permission

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root   root    179 Aug 12 12:31 start_indexjs
```

then restart crond service using below command

```
systemctl restart crond.service
```

After all this my cron job running but when `/home/guest/start_indexjs > /var/log/start_indexjs.log` running in cron job my "index.js" not running there is no process is running with index.js using following command

```
ps -ef | grep index.js
```

Comment: does the script run stand alone? That is, does it work when you execute manually `/home/guest/start_indexjs`? (would be a good idea to add a .sh extension to the script, so that it is more clear that it is so).

Comment: Also, it may happen that `pgrep` matches itself.

Comment: @fedorqui yes script run stand alone. it work when you execute manually "/home/guest/start_indexjs"

Comment: Could you also clarify the last sentence _After all this my cron job running but when /home/guest/start_indexjs > /var/log/start_indexjs.log running in cron job my "index.js" not running there is no process is running with index.js using following command_? It is a bit unclear what is happening.

Comment: @fedorqui When my "*/1 * * * * root /home/guest/start_indexjs > /var/log/start_indexjs.log" run. After that there is no process is running with "index.js"

Comment: @fedorqui /home/guest/start_indexjs file could not start my "nohup node /root/demo/index.js > /root/index-nohup.log &" when this file execute with crontab.

Comment: Uhms, this is strange. I would debug by doing something like `touch /tmp/sample_file` in the `if` condition to see if it enters there. Also, you may want to use `crontab -e` to set crontab instead of writing to `/etc/crontab` directly. It is safer

Comment: @fedorqui please suggest me how can i run "nohup node /root/demo/index.js > /root/index-nohup.log &" command using bash/shell script.

Comment: I would give a try to `nohup node /root/demo/index.js &` alone. If it works, then add the redirect to the log file. Also interesting to check [Node.js as a background service](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4018154/1983854)

Comment: So did you find out what is the issue?

Comment: @fedorqui No, I did not find any issue. If you get any issue then please help me out to fix this.