# nodejs running as service and console.log on centos

Tags: node.js, service, centos7, console.log, systemd

Referring to [Running Nodejs As a Service - Systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042953/339122)

I can't debug with `console.log('running on ...');`

Here is my nodeserver.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Nodeserver

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /var/www/web/nodeserver.js
Type=simple
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and this is nodeserver.js:

```
process.chdir(__dirname);
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require('./config');

app.listen(3000, function(){ console.log('running on port 3000'); });
```

the server is running perfectly, no errors, and I can access it from browser like: `http://example.com:3000`

every thing is great.

Now, ff I run the server like `node server.js`, it prints `running on port 3000` in the terminal screen, but when I start it as service like: `systemctl start nodeserver`, the server start but it doesn't log any thing in the terminal.

I found something about `journalctl`, but that's not good enough. Something missing somewhere.

How can I get results from `console.log` when start it from service?

Comment: Why not just write directly to a file when stdout is not a tty?

Comment: Because I need to refresh that file every time to see whats happening, and that can slow the work.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh the file?" If you're reading the log from a terminal, you can just `tail -f` the file.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: @mscdex Ok, what if my server.js has an error that stops it from starting, the file wouldn't be updated to see whats wrong, I need to run `node server.js` again!

Comment: Voting down without any explanation is uncool!