# Exec command time out Error when running nodejs app using puppet

Tags: node.js, puppet

I am cloning my repo and running  my nodejs application using puppet. please find the code below:

```
package { 'git':
  ensure => 'latest',
}

vcsrepo { "/nodejs-helloworld":
  ensure   => latest,
  provider => git,
  require  => [ Package["git"] ],
  source   => "git@gitlab.abc.dev.net:hello-world/nodejs-helloworld.git",
  revision => 'master',
  before   => Exec['/usr/local/bin/npm install;/usr/local/bin/npm start'],
}

exec { '/usr/local/bin/npm install;/usr/local/bin/npm start':
  cwd         => '/nodejs-helloworld',
  subscribe   => Vcsrepo['/nodejs-helloworld'],
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

My repository is cloned, my application is running fine, and `npm test` also works. Everything works fine. However, I get an exec command time out error.

Error log:

```
[root@ip-*******/]# puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for ip-**************
Info: Applying configuration version '1474433486'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[install-node-version-manager-global]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[install-node-version-manager-latest]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Vcsrepo[/nodejs-helloworld]/ensure: Creating repository from latest
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Vcsrepo[/nodejs-helloworld]/ensure: created
Info: /Stage[main]/Main/Vcsrepo[/nodejs-helloworld]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[/usr/local/bin/npm install;/usr/local/bin/npm start]
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[/usr/local/bin/npm install;/usr/local/bin/npm start]: Failed to call refresh: Command exceeded timeout
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[/usr/local/bin/npm install;/usr/local/bin/npm start]: Command exceeded timeout
Notice: Finished catalog run in 302.86 seconds
```

As you can see here, even though I get an exec command timeout error, my app is running and `npm test` works.

```
 [root@ip-********* nodejs-helloworld]# netstat -anp 2> /dev/null | grep :3000
    tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      17630/node
 [root@ip-********* nodejs-helloworld]# npm test

    > nodejs-helloworld@1.0.0 test /nodejs-helloworld
    > mocha



      Test HelloWorld
        ✓ Should have the root route (46ms)
        ✓ Should have a hello world response


      2 passing (66ms)
```

Can anyone please tell me how to avoid the exec command timeout error?

Comment: You should really add a `logoutput` to the `exec` resource to see what is going on that may cause a timeout and then report back.

Comment: exec { '/usr/local/bin/npm install;/usr/local/bin/npm start':
  command     => '/usr/local/bin/npm install;/usr/local/bin/npm start',
  cwd         => '/nodejs-helloworld',
  logoutput   => true,
  subscribe   => Vcsrepo['/nodejs-helloworld'],
  refreshonly => true,
}

Comment: getting the same error connection time out as mentioned in error log.

Comment: [root@ip-******** nodejs-helloworld]# npm start
> nodejs-helloworld@1.0.0 start /nodejs-helloworld
> node index.js

HelloWorld running on 3000
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 npm start



But i dont wana stop it. so i usually open another terminal and do 'npm test' 
I guess when i do the same using puppet it keeps  waiting after doing 'npm start'.

Comment: So nothing is being output to stdout or stderr during that exec?

Comment: No what i mentioned in question same error  "Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[/usr/local/bin/npm install;/usr/local/bin/npm start]: Failed to call refresh: Command exceeded timeout
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[/usr/local/bin/npm install;/usr/local/bin/npm start]: Command exceeded timeout"

Comment: Does the `npm start` command properly background itself when run from the console?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong what seems to be the problem is that, when you run `npm start`, it runs your application but it doesn't exit, and you don't want that because you want to keep your application running, however puppet expects it to exit at some point.

What you should do instead is to make the `exec` resource start your application in the background. You can have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4018154/774086) where the answers describe various tools to easily achieve this.