# How to set a node server to run even after closing putty?

Tags: node.js, server, forever

when am trying forever server.js its showing warning messages as 
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms

how to overcome this and keep my server on forever?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js as a background service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service)

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple options to 'daemonise' a Node.js server, you could use [screen](https://superuser.com/questions/632205/continue-ssh-background-task-jobs-when-closing-ssh) or [tmux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session) to run the shell in the background - tmux being the my recommended choice in that situation.

If you want to stick to a node.js toolset, the lightest weight option would be [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever), however if you're looking for a more advanced solution you should check out [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/).

I used to run processes with a tmux session, I then moved to forever, but found it a chore to use in a multi-user environment, I've been using PM2 for some time now with no issues.

[If you're on linux this solution from another StackOverflow user may be worth considering - actually it's probably the best solution of all.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042953/2344348)

Answer (score 1):

`forever start -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log server.js`
https://github.com/foreverjs/forever#usage