# Fixing a systemd service 203/EXEC failure (no such file or directory)

Tags: bash, systemd

I'm trying to set up a simple systemd timer to run a bash script every day at midnight.

`systemctl --user status backup.service` fails and logs the following:

```
backup.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/user/.scripts/backup.sh: No such file or directory.

backup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Failed to start backup.
backup.service: Unit entered failed state.
backup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'm lost, since the files and directories exist. The script is executable and, just to check, I've even set permissions to 777.

Some background:

The `backup.timer` and `backup.service` unit files are located in `/home/user/.config/systemd/user`.

`backup.timer` is loaded and active, and currently waiting for midnight.

Here's what it looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs backup at 0000

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
Unit=backup.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here's `backup.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=backup

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/user/.scripts/backup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And lastly, this is a paraphrase of `backup.sh`:

```
#!/usr/env/bin bash

rsync -a --delete --quiet /home/user/directory/ /mnt/drive/directory-backup/
```

The script runs fine if I execute it myself.

Not sure if it matters, but I use `fish` as my shell (started from .bashrc).

I'm happy to post the full script if that's helpful.

Comment: What does `ls -l /home/user/.scripts/backup.sh` output ? The start of your backup.sh script looks very strange: `#!/user/env/bin bash` , does the executable `/user/env/bin` actually exist ? Are you sure you didn't mean `/usr/bin/env` or `/home/user/bin/env`  ?

Comment: ```ls``` outputs ```-rwxrwxrwx 1 dwrz dwrz 1470 Aug 11 01:57 /home/user/.scripts/backup.sh```.


And my apologies -- the typo in the shebang was when I was copying things over to here. It's ```/usr/``` in the script.

Comment: Aside: Starting fish from `.bashrc` is a **really** bad idea. Update your `/etc/passwd` entry to directly specify fish, don't confuse programs that may intentionally want to run an interactive bash instance by making it start a different, incompatible shell instead.

Comment: As for the immediate issue at hand, I'd start by reproducing it with [Sysdig](http://sysdig.org/) tracing execution; that way you can find the exact syscall that fails and extract pertinent details (active PATH, uid, gid, etc).

Comment: BTW, **is** there a `PATH` set when your service is invoked? If `env bash` can't find `bash` because there's no `PATH`, that would cause your bug. Setting `Environment=PATH=/bin:/usr/bin` or otherwise a known-good value in the `.service` wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Thanks so much, Charles. I didn't set ```fish``` in ```/etc/passwd```, as the [Arch Wiki advises against it](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fish), but I appreciate the head's up and will look into that as well. For now I tried two things: (1) specifying the ```PATH``` in the service file, (2) just using ```#!/bin/bash``` in the script (which still runs fine when I execute it myself). I'm still getting the same error with systemd (made sure to ```daemon-reload```). I'm going to look at ```sysdig``` now.

Comment: Looking into /var/messages may reveal some more details about the failure. Also serverfault has some questions on this topic, see: https://serverfault.com/questions/957084/

Answer (score 206, accepted):

I think I found the answer:

In the `.service` file, I needed to add `/bin/bash` before the path to the script.

For example, for backup.service:

`ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/.scripts/backup.sh`

As opposed to:

`ExecStart=/home/user/.scripts/backup.sh`

I'm not sure why. Perhaps `fish`. On the other hand, I have another script running for my email, and the service file seems to run fine without `/bin/bash`. It does use `default.target` instead `multi-user.target`, though.

Most of the tutorials I came across don't prepend `/bin/bash`, but I then saw [this SO answer which had it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198444/run-script-every-30-min-with-systemd), and figured it was worth a try.

The service file executes the script, and the timer is listed in `systemctl --user list-timers`, so hopefully this will work.

Update: I can confirm that everything is working now.

Comment: This solved it for me. The reason it works with other scripts is that they have a shebang (#!/bin/bash) at the beginning while this particular one had not.

Comment: this work around is super annoying, writing a `#!` line tells the kernel what interpreter to use, now I have to mirror this information in a unit file for applications that aren't singletons -_- what

Comment: Even when the executable is not a bash script, such as in my case, `jupyter` on CentOS 7, `/bin/bash -c "..."` is necessary. I think it is because it's a python script, and it has a shebang of python at the very beginning.

Comment: Scripts should have an interpreter, otherwise they're not a script. You should fix the script, rather than add bash to your `.service` file.

Comment: Sometimes you need a `chmod +x /home/user/.scripts/backup.sh`.

Comment: In my case I was missing .sh extension

Comment: I had `#!/bin/bash` and it still didn't work. I don't know why, but `/bin/bash` prefix in `.service` file was still necessary

Comment: I had a similar issue (nodejs file background process in my case) and had setup it like this... Works like a charm! Had to change the file rights to allow executing it though.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me - for some reason, the shebang line simply does not work at all with systemd (Ubuntu 18.04), despite all the comments saying to add it. Everything else was set correctly too - user, group, working directory, etc.

Comment: Well this worked, strange part is that the file had been working for months prior. Not sure why it wanted the update now.

Comment: new error : Main process exited, code=exited, status=243/n/a

Comment: RHEL-9 requires "/bin/bash" EVEN if the script executes fine from command-line

Answer (score 19):

To simplify, make sure to add a hash bang to the top of your ExecStart script, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

python -u alwayson.py
```

Answer (score 10):

When this happened to me it was because my script had DOS line endings, which always messes up the shebang line at the top of the script. I changed it to Unix line endings and it worked.

Comment: You saved my life! I just added `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the first line of the `.sh` then worked.

Answer (score 10):

I ran across a `Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC` today as well and my bug was that I forgot to add the executable bit to the file.

Comment: I came here and read the marked answer and discovered before reading your answer that simply doing a chmod 700 <script> resolved my issue.  This should be marked as the correct answer.  I did not have to add /bin/bash <script-start> as the marked answer states.

Answer (score 8):

If that is a copy/paste from your script, you've permuted this line:

```
#!/usr/env/bin bash
```

There's no `#!/usr/env/bin`, you meant `#!/usr/bin/env`.

Comment: Nice catch! The script is correct now, but it's possible I may have fixed it afterwards. It if it was a copy-paste, this would have explained it.

Answer (score 3):

try running:

```sh
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and then again run

```sh
service <yourservice> status
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, changed the permission and added executable permission

use `chmod +x /etc/systemd/system/<service-filename>`

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I actually used the answer from [How do I run a node.js app as a background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/how-do-i-run-a-node-js-app-as-a-background-service) combined with what dwrz said above. In my case, I was creating a Discord bot that needed to be able to run when I was not around.

With this service in place, I initially got the same error that the initial poster did, which brought me here. I was missing the `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the top of my executed node.js script.

Since then, no problems, although I intend to see what else can be extended to the service itself.