# Failed to start Redis In-Memory Data Store. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install redis on my AWS server. I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on it. I am following steps to install redis from [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-redis-from-source-on-ubuntu-18-04) article.

When i run `sudo systemctl status redis` command i am getting below error.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcZPx.png)

I tried to edit `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` file and added `Type=forking` under `[Service]` section but still getting the same error.

Can anyone suggest me how i can get it fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could add the log file from the Redis server? It is usually located under `/var/log`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776003/fixing-a-systemd-service-203-exec-failure-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Thanks for your valuable replies @Niloct and Itamar Haber. After spending hours by myself, I finally get the installation done by hiring a person and its now working fine.

Comment: Hello, do you mind to share how to fix this? I have the same problem with you. I have been siting for almost 24h to fix just this problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered this problem, then I tried to check it again.
Finally, I found that when I authorized `/var/lib/redis`, I entered the wrong command, causing the redis account to have no access to `/var/lib/redis`.

```
sudo chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis
sudo systemctl restart redis
```

succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

Based on same digitalocean tutorial, actually it's running fine.

Run this command `sudo systemctl restart redis.service`, we get (showing "**failed**" on last line):

```
● redis.service - Redis In-Memory Data Store
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-06-28 12:03:11 +03; 1min 0s ago
  Process: 20428 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=
 Main PID: 20428 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jun 28 12:03:11 XYZ systemd[1]: redis.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restar
Jun 28 12:03:11 XYZ systemd[1]: redis.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 
Jun 28 12:03:11 XYZ systemd[1]: Stopped Redis In-Memory Data Store.
Jun 28 12:03:11 XYZ systemd[1]: redis.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 28 12:03:11 XYZ systemd[1]: redis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 28 12:03:11 XYZ systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis In-Memory Data Store.
```

But if you run `sudo service redis-server status`, we get (showing "**running**" on 3rd line):

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-06-28 11:50:13 +03; 19min ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
  Process: 19278 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19371 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCC
 Main PID: 19382 (redis-server)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
           └─19382 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379

Jun 28 11:50:13 XYZ systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
Jun 28 11:50:13 XYZ systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/redis/red
Jun 28 11:50:13 XYZ systemd[1]: Started Advanced key-value store.
```

After searching for hours, it seems like it's some difference between `systemctl` & `service` and nothing more, but the actual redis server is running fine. Corrects me if that's not the case. Here's the link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/903354/difference-between-systemctl-and-service-commands

You can even check if redis is working fine, by `redis-cli ping`, should print `PONG`