# How to debug 203/EXEC when running dotnet appname.dll in redhat 7 systemd?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redhat, systemd, systemctl

Been trying to debug for 4 days now.
I have an asp.net core 2 web app I'm trying to run in Redhat linux 7.1 systemd. The dll works fine when I run it manually, but fails when trying to run through systemd.

Output from systemctl

> web.service - WebServiceLayer
>   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/user/web.service; enabled; vendor preset: >disabled)
>
> Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-04-28 >12:49:01 CDT; 2s ago
>
> Process: 13588 ExecStart=/microsoft/dotnetcore/dotnet /local/lfs1/ServiceLayer/WebServiceLayer/WebServiceLayer.dll (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
>
> Main PID: 13588 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
>
> Apr 28 12:49:01 mymachine.net systemd[1]: web.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
>
> Apr 28 12:49:01 mymachine.net systemd[1]: Unit web.service entered failed state.
>
> Apr 28 12:49:01 mymachine.net systemd[1]: web.service failed.

Here's the basic service file

```
mymachine home/username $ cat /etc/systemd/user/web.service
[Unit]
Description=WebServiceLayer
After=syslog.target

[Service]

User=serviceUser

Group=serviceUser
PIDFile=/tmp/$i.pid
WorkingDirectory=%h
Environment="PATH=/microsoft/dotnetcore/"
ExecStart="/microsoft/dotnetcore/dotnet /local/lfs1/ServiceLayer/WebServiceLayer/WebServiceLayer.dll"
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
StartLimitBurst=10
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For reference, when I start the dll normally I get no errors:

> [serviceUser@mymachine]: /microsoft/dotnetcore/dotnet /local/lfs1/ServiceLayer/WebServiceLayer/WebServiceLayer.dll
>   Hosting environment: Production
>   Content root path: /home/serviceUser Now listening on: "http://0.0.0.0:7777" Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

I have looked at [Fixing a systemd service 203/EXEC failure (no such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776003/fixing-a-systemd-service-203-exec-failure-no-such-file-or-directory) but that didn't help my issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code from Program.cs in .dll file:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // NLog: setup the logger first to catch all errors
            var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                logger.Debug("init main");
                CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //NLog: catch setup errors
                logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls(urls: "http://mymachine.net:7777") 
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                })
                .UseNLog();  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well from the output you get it's hard to know what is going on. I would advise you yo configure some extra logging.

First you could configure logging to a text file to get more details. Some more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

After that you could place a big try / catch around the code in the main method and log the exception.

The only quick check which comes in my mind, does the serviceUser has enough rights to access the dll or config files or any related stuff?

Comment: Thanks, so I already have NLog implemented in the actual code itself. Problem is that execution doesn't even get to the Main function:

Comment: See my last addition, does the serviceUser has enough rights? And you can try to use sudo to run the process under that serviceUser to see how it than behaves.

Comment: Yes, serviceUser can run the dll manually
[serviceUser@mymachine]: /microsoft/dotnetcore/dotnet /local/lfs1/ServiceLayer/WebServiceLayer/WebServiceLayer.dll Hosting environment: Production Content root path: /home/serviceUser Now listening on: "http://0.0.0.0:7777" Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Comment: Did you check syslog for more details on the error?

Comment: Ok, so I found this in the /var/logs/messages file:
Apr 28 14:09:13 myMachine systemd: Failed at step EXEC spawning /microsoft/dotnetcore/dotnet /local/lfs1/ServiceLayer/WebServiceLayer/WebServiceLayer.dll: No such file or directory.  

Which doesn't make sense because when I do an ls on those two directories, they exist.

Comment: you could try to find out which one causes the problem bij doing just dotnet witout specifying the dll. if it works, you get just some help output, othrwise the same error

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try that tomorrow.