# System Unit File always failed

Tags: go, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I need to deploy my Go app to aws (ec2 instance), with Ubuntu 18.04, however I can't manage to make it run using the systemd. Here is my created service (/lib/systemd/system/go.service)

```
 [Unit]
 Description=go api

 [Service]
 Type=simple
 Restart=always
 RestartSec=5s
 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/go/amutan

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the result when I run `sudo service go start`, `sudo service go status`

```
go.service - go api
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/go.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-02-25 05
Process: 7326 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/go/amutan (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Main PID: 7326 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Feb 25 05:22:46 ip-172-31-27-28 systemd[1]: Stopped go api.
Feb 25 05:22:46 ip-172-31-27-28 systemd[1]: Started go api.
Feb 25 05:22:46 ip-172-31-27-28 systemd[1]: go.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 25 05:22:46 ip-172-31-27-28 systemd[1]: go.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My go binary resides in /home/ubuntu/go which is named amutan.

Any ideas?

Comment: The lines are not fully copied (cut in the middle), and the interesting part of the error message is often at the end. Could you edit the question with the full output?

Comment: @VonC yeah, updated error logs

Comment: Not the first lines though ": enab"...

Comment: its enable), updated though

Comment: I was hoping for more after code=exited, status=203/EXEC, like "file not found" or something similar which might have helped.

Comment: unfortunately, I was hoping too for a more informative error output

Comment: running the go binary manually is ok ./amutan

Comment: Yes but this is done as you, not as root (which is used when running the service) Then environment variables will differ.

Comment: should I explicitly add User=root ?

Comment: yeah adding User=root and Group=root does not helped Tried also to reboot the ec2 instance, still not working

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173 Feb 25 05:53 go.service
 is the output when tryng ls -l go.service

Comment: The opposite: User = you

Comment: doesnt help either

Comment: you can try this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776003/fixing-a-systemd-service-203-exec-failure-no-such-file-or-directory)..

Comment: if that is also not working you could try System V init script..

Answer (score 1):

That error message is in the [official documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) as

> 203 EXIT_EXEC   The actual process execution failed (specifically, the
>   execve(2) system call). Most likely this is caused by a missing or
>   non-accessible executable file.

So check permissions, the exact path and things like selinux settings