# How to run Node.js 24/7 in Server CentOS 6.5?

Tags: node.js, centos

I know I can run Node.js on server with command line **`node app.js`**.

But when I am out of control server, the session will be close and end my command. I don't know how to make a service run Node.js 24/7 like another in Server.

I follow [**this**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-run-a-node-js-app-on-centos-6-4-64bit) post, but I'm not using express.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a node.js app as a background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/how-do-i-run-a-node-js-app-as-a-background-service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run it using forever , it helps the server to restart whenever the node server get crashed. https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: this can be, because i connect to server on SSH, when i'm logout i will be close then. i need to know how to make simple service run on Centos 6.5. In this service run code to run NodeJS on Centos

Comment: if you do forever start app.js and thn logout from ur ssh ur server will be still on and working .

Answer (score 2):

You can make it happen by many ways.

1. You can append `&` in the command line to make the node server run in background.

   ```
   node app.js > stdout.txt > stderr.txt &
   ```
2. Via process manager [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/), It gives more features, you can monitor all the processes `pm2 monit`, auto restart, [etc](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/)

   ```
   npm install pm2 -g

   pm2 start app.js
   ```
3. or, using following npm packages

[Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) - `nodemon app.js`

[Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) - `forever start app.js`.