# how to restart a nodejs server on linux AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

So I'm really new into loading the node server on AWS,
basically I followed some guide to start node from etc/init

so I have a file like that in etc/init

menuserver.conf

```
#!upstart
description "menu-creator server"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn:
respawn
respawn limit 99 5

env NODE_ENV=development

# Warning: this runs node as root user, which is a security risk
# in many scenarios, but upstart-ing a process as a non-root user
# is outside the scope of this question
exec node /home/ec2-user/MenuCreator/app.js >> /var/log/yourappname.log 2>&1
```

I have updated the server code, and wish to restart the server, how to do it?
as I'm just starting out, I don't care so much for the security risks.

I've tried etc/init.d/menuserver restart,
but actually menuserver isn't found in init.d.

looking for a quick way to restart the program, and also for a long term good practice guide for how to setup and restart the server.
(I think I heard Forever is recommended... is it?)

Comment: Have you tried this ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042953/4896841

Comment: I'm kinda lost on what is the right way into doing this, but for now I've succeeded to stop the service. I will go thorough th link

Comment: If you're using upstart for task management then you should read the upstart documentation. It will tell you how to stop/start tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo stop/start/restart service name worked for me,
example:

sudo stop menuserver

Answer (score 2):

Try setting pm2 on server. You can easily restart server then. Study more about pm2 
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/