# React build run on server using pm2

Tags: reactjs, pm2, forever, serve, react-scripts

I have compiled my react app using

```
react-scripts build
```

And it generated a build\ folder in the root directory of App.
I am running the build\ folder using

```
sudo serve -T -p 443 build/
```

This runs my React app successfully on HTTPS since I am passing `-T`. But I needed to run my app forever using any of the modules available. I was looking into node modules **forever** & **pm2**.
I am trying to using pm2 in the following way:

```
sudo pm2 serve -T -p 443 build/
```

It throws:

```
error: unknown option `-T'
```

and when I use:

```
sudo pm2 serve -p 443 build/
```

It works on console but I am not able to access my app from URL

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-XXX-XX-XXX UI]$ sudo pm2 serve -p 443 build/
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Starting /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API/Serve.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
[PM2] Serving /var/www/html/UI/build on port 8080
┌─────────────────────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ App name                │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ user │ watching │
├─────────────────────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼──────┼──────────┤
│ static-page-server-8080 │ 0  │ fork │ 26609 │ online │ 0       │ 0s     │ 2%  │ 21.7 MB   │ root │ disabled │
└─────────────────────────┴────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴──────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

Can someone help me with this?
Or if there is any other way to run your react app on production forever.

Comment: just to double check,  is there a reason why you want to be hosting your own front end? something like https://www.netlify.com/ is probably better

Comment: Just a quick note that if you use most Linux distributions, you don't need PM2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/how-do-i-run-a-node-js-app-as-a-background-service

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use a `pm2` JSON config to run arbitrary binaries:

`app.config.json`

```
{
  apps : [
    {
      name      : "your-app",
      script    : "npx",
      interpreter: "none",
      args: "serve -p 8443 -T"
    }
  ]
}
```

To start:

```
pm2 start app.config.json
```

`interpreter: "none"` tells `pm2` not to treat the script like a JavaScript file when executing, and instead to treat it like an ordinary binary.

If you have a `serve` binary in the same directory as the app config, you can execute `serve` directly instead of `npx`.

Comment: `args: "serve -p 8443 -T"` this command tells that app will run on 8443 port? right?

Comment: @ReemaParakh That's correct.

`script: "npx"` tells pm2 to execute the `npx` command, and `args: "serve -p 8443 -T"` will be passed to `npx` as arguments.

So ultimately, pm2 will run

`npx serve -p 8443 -T`

Comment: It's not clear to me, what is the name?  where to keep this file? and where to give our root app.js file?

Comment: @151291 You should keep this file in your root folder along with your package.json file. The name : "your-app" is like when you run pm2 directly on terminal `pm2 start index.js --name your-app`

Comment: I don't think pm2 serve works properly with routes. It just serves files statically and mistakes routes for directory paths.

Comment: I tried this and obtained a beautiful table in the terminal, but nothing in the browser . *****

I tried servername:3011 and servername:3011/appname
******
My json file looks like this:
{
    "apps" : [
      {
        "name"      : "confluence2zoomin",
        "script"    : "npx",
        "interpreter": "none",
        "args": "serve -p 3011 -T"
      }
    ]
  }

Comment: Works well with React Router, serve index from all URLs

Answer (score 19):

Use below command it worked for me

first build your react application and then hit this command inside your application folder .

```
pm2 serve build/ 3000 --name "react-build" --spa
```

Comment: What is this `--spa` flag for?

Comment: That's for serving Single Page Application(SPA) 
Refer: Serving SPA: redirect all to index.html @ https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/expose/

Comment: Without --spa it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

@bgran provided a nice solution. As an alternative, I dare to suggest you can add this **deploy** to your script in package.json

```
"deploy": "pm2 start ./server.sh --name yourAppName",
```

Then in the same directory as the package.json, create an executable **server.sh**:

```
echo "Serving yourAppName!"
serve -s build
```

Don't forget to make server.sh an executable by running:

```
chmod +x server.sh
```

Now it's party time! Deploy your app by running

```
npm run deploy
```

Done!

Comment: How can I give reference to only the "dist" folder (which has all bundled changes) here?

Comment: This worked in combination with app.config.json as described in previous file.  If i did not write my own server.sh it would not execute. Thanks!

Comment: and also add #!/bin/bash at the top of the bash file

Comment: Not a good answer. Running server.sh like this, leaks memory and causes the ec2 instance to lag

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to run React project using pm2 then try to run below command

```
pm2 start --name <app name<app name>> npm -- start
```

Answer (score 2):

create **run.sh** file

put below command inside run.sh file

**serve -s build**

and save.

Then run this command.

sudo pm2 start run.sh --name app-name