# What is the best way to run a Node.js script as service in Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have a Node.js script that keeps my [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) database and the [CRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer-relationship_management) database synced in real-time.

I want to run this script as a background task on my Ubuntu server. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/how-do-i-run-a-node-js-app-as-a-background-service), but it doesn't work for me. Is there another approach to reach this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you just want to start your application, you could use [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) or [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) for running and auto-restarting on crash. **However, this is not a background task**.

For a background task that starts on server reboot, the post you linked is the right way to go. If it didn't work, maybe this article will help you. This is from official Express site: *[Process managers for Express apps](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/pm.html#systemd)*

Basically, you create

```
[Unit]
Description="My Express App"

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node server.js
WorkingDirectory=/project/absolute/path
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=MyApp
Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=8080

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Into a `/etc/systemd/system/my-app.service` file and then use [`systemctl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Core_components_and_libraries) to start it:

```
systemctl enable my-app.service
systemctl start my-app.service
```

Now this assumes your Linux distribution works with systemctl. If your Linux distribution works with upstart or something else, then you need to google up the instruction for that process manager.