# running node js app in background in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, discord

I have a nodejs compiled application that I run from a terminal window on my ubuntu vps.Is there a way to run it in the background, meaning i can afford to close my terminal window and it still works. Note this exe prints the messages on the terminal window when its running

tried PM2, it errors out saying "awaiting restart"
tried nohup, it does not error out and shows process has started but exe does not what it shall do, meaning its not working.
if i do ./app , it works but then i can not close the terminal window.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a direct way with the nodejs command but you could consider running your node app in a Docker container

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a node.js app as a background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/how-do-i-run-a-node-js-app-as-a-background-service)

Comment: [Docker](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) is a really good option
You can also use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Comment: You should use `pm2` check why it throws an error. you can find it on the keymetrics dashboard

Comment: error i get when i run it via PM2 
`2|bot      | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:468
2|bot      |   if (request.charAt(0) !== '.' ||
2|bot      |               ^
2|bot      |
2|bot      | TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined`

Comment: with forever i get `Forever processing file: ./bot` but it never runs. No errors

Comment: Thanks @JackRed , I will check Docker now.

Answer (score 0):

used tmux, loving it so far.
think might use PM2 with tmux where i can.