# NestJS server dies when console is closed?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, deployment, nestjs

I created folder for project, copy `package.json` and run `npm install`, build locally nestjs project and copy dist into server. Then ran in console `node dist/main.js`. For testing I used a base NestJS project (nest new ...) which only return "Hello word" on 3000 port.

Server work fine, but after close of console will stop.

I think problem on VPS (Ubuntu) settings or may be need to add some parameters to NestJS.

Why it not work constantly?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a node.js app as a background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/how-do-i-run-a-node-js-app-as-a-background-service)

Comment: O! Seems this may resolve my issue. I'll try implement it in closest days and write result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved problem with npm forever  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever
install it globally  - npm install forever -g
then got to project dir and run - forever start dist/main.js
Seems all work fine.

Comment: what If I need to run with --watch?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can run --watch with forever. When I need use dev mode I write npm run start:dev and not close console. By the way last time I prefer use pm2 instead forever https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2