# Why hangup signal is caught even with nohup?

Tags: linux, go, signals

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/signal"

    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func main() {
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, unix.SIGHUP)

    go func() {
        s := <-sigs
        log.Info("OS signal: " + s.String())
    }()

    DoSomething()
}
```

I compiled the Go code above and executed with following command:

```
nohup ./build_linux > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

But the process still catches HANGUP signal when I exit the terminal.

Seems like `signal.Notify` has higher priority, and `nohup` command has no effect.

What's going on and why `nohup` does not prevent sending hangup signal to process?

Comment: I don't know anything about the inner workings of nohup, but I assume it just installs an ignore-handler for the sighup signal and then exec's your application (which replaces the process), and your signal handler overrides the previous handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Check `signal.Ignored()` first:

```
if !signal.Ignored(unix.SIGHUP) {
    signal.Notify(sigs, unix.SIGHUP)
}
```

#### Long

[tkausl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64479821/why-hangup-signal-is-caught-even-with-nohup#comment114015475_64479821) has the correct answer: running:

```
nohup ./build_linux
```

from the command line launches the `./build_linux` program with `SIGHUP` set to `SIG_IGN` (all of these signal names being generic Linux names, rather than Go package names).  If you install your own handler for `SIGHUP`, this overrides the current setting of `SIGHUP`.

In general, in Unix/Linux programs, the correct pattern is to *test* whether the signal is *currently ignored* before (or as part of) installing a signal-catch function.  If the signal *is* ignored, restore it to being ignored.

To make this process completely reliable, the most efficient correct pattern to use is:

- hold off the signal (perhaps all signals);
- install any desired handler, which returns the current disposition of the signal;
- if the current disposition was `SIG_IGN`, return the disposition to `SIG_IGN`;
- release the signal.

The holding-and-releasing is done with the Unix/Linux `sigprocmask` or `pthread_sigmask` system call.  The one to use depends on whether you're using threads.  Go of course does use threads; see, e.g., [this patch](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/41183d015d17ab537287599e2bf72ca1cdeafb55) to the Cgo runtime startup from 2013 (fixes [issue #6811](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6811)).

Since Go 1.11, which introduced [`signal.Ignored`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#Ignored), you can just use that, as the Go runtime has already done all the appropriate hold / set-and-test / restore sequence at startup, and cached the result.  One should *definitely* use this for `SIGHUP` so as to obey the `nohup` convention.  One should generally use this for `SIGINT` and other keyboard signals as well, and there's almost<sup>1</sup> no reason *not* to use it for all signals.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Jenkins, or some version or versions of Jenkins at least, apparently (incorrectly) sets all signals to be ignored at startup when running test suites.