# It is possible run application without listening port?

Tags: nestjs

It is possible run application without listening port?
I just want to run scheduled tasks

Comment: This might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/how-do-i-run-a-node-js-app-as-a-background-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, Nestjs offers **Standalone applications**, with it you can mount a Nest application without any network listeners. to implement it, you have to edit your main.js function by :

```
    async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
  // application logic...
}
bootstrap();
```

For more details visit [Standalone applications](https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications#standalone-applications)

Comment: Thanks, it's what i wanted

Comment: I followed this, but the application is killed immediately.