# Running Node services in background

Tags: node.js

When I restart the ubuntu server the node.js services in the server are not running in the background.
I need to connect to the server and start the services whenever I restart the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a node.js app as a background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/how-do-i-run-a-node-js-app-as-a-background-service)

Comment: Enable the service to autostart? What are you using to handle your node process, systemd? -> `systemctl enable <service name>`

Answer (score 1):

Use PM2.

To install PM2:

```
npm install -g pm2
```

To start a node.js process:

```
pm2 start -n "My task name" /path/to/node/script
```

To list process:

```
pm2 list
```

To restart manually a process (after update for example):

```
pm2 restart <id of process>
```

PM2 will handle restart automatically in some case, or you can also tell PM2 to restart node process if script change. And many other cool things.

Comment: You can also save your pM2 configuration with ``pm2 save`` and restore with ``pm2 resurect``

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pm2 is a advanced process manager for production Node.js applications. Load balancer, logs facility, startup script, micro service management, at a glance.

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/

With this you can run in background